# CSS 3 nth of type restricted to class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is there a way to limit CSS 3's `nth-of-type` to a class? I've got a dynamic number of `section` elements with different classes designating their layout needs. I'd like to grab every third `.module`, but it seems that `nth-of-type` looks up classes element type and then calculates the type. Instead I'd like to limit it to only `.module`s.

JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/e2BAq/1/

HTML:

```
<section class="featured video">
    <h1>VIDEO</h1>
</section>
<section class="featured module">
    <h1>NOT A VIDEO</h1>
</section>
<section class="featured module">
    <h1>NOT A VIDEO</h1>
</section>
<section class="featured module">
    <h1>NOT A VIDEO (3)</h1>
</section>
<section class="featured module">
    <h1>NOT A VIDEO</h1>
</section>
<section class="featured module">
    <h1>NOT A VIDEO</h1>
</section>
<section class="featured module">
    <h1>NOT A VIDEO (6)</h1>
</section>
```

​CSS:

```
.featured {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 3.5% 2em 0;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}

.featured.module:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  padding-right: 0;
  background: red;
}

.featured.video {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 0 2em 0;
  float: none;
}​
```

Comment: `:nth-of-type()` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way (at least none I know of) to select `nth-of-type` of a class, since `nth-of-class` doesn’t exist. You will probably have to add a new class to every third `.module` manually.

Comment: There cannot be a way to select `:nth-of-type()` of a class, because `:nth-of-type()` only selects the nth child of its **type**. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name

Comment: The behaviour of nth-of-type is so unexpected. .thing:nth-of-type(1) is actually div.thing:nth-of-type(1) so if you don't include the element in your selectors it's confusing. If you don't think this is unexpected then why does it cause so much confusion amongst developers?

Comment: @Dominic Watson: I think the problem here is that most authors aren't familiar with the term "element type", which is used by Selectors in place of the HTML/XML-specific term "tag name". That's clarified a little bit in Selectors level 4, but not by very much.

Comment: That's quite sad and unintuitive in my humble opinion. Should be nth entity of matching selector, not just a tag name. CSS limitation, unfortunetely.

Answer (score 44):

It seems what you really want is the [css4 :nth-match selector](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/), but it's not really supported in most browsers yet, so currently, the only way to do it is with JavaScript:

```
$(".featured.module").filter(function(index, element){
    return index % 3 == 2;
}).addClass("third");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3af16dj/

Comment: Why do you pass the `element` as an argument to the function? It's not used

Comment: because I think it's useful reference for SO readers, when I wrote this answer I had to check the documentation to remember which argument came first. I also assume some people will modify the code.

Comment: No idea who would downvote this, provides a current answer and a (still) future-answer. To save anyone the effort if you consider it, `nth-match` still isn't supported in Chrome in 2017. No need to check the other browsers for me.

Comment: Still useful near the end of 2017 - I wanted to replace li:class:nth-match(4n+1) and I changed the function above to return index % 4 == 0;  Thanks for the fiddle, so I could play around and get it right!

Comment: @RegularJoe guess it was downvoted because element and index are in swapped order as one usually is used to.. but it works :D

Comment: I hope they get rid of `nth-of-type()` eventually, because it makes things unobvious. If I wanted nth entity of given tag name, I could do `div:nth-match-selector(3)`, for example.