# css selector nth-of-type not work

Tags: css-selectors, scrapy

I want to know how to choose the `www.test.com?p=2`  with css selector

I use `next_page = sel.css(u"div.page_sp > a.pagecl:nth-of-type(2)::attr(href)")`

www.test.com?p=2

But it didn't work
Please guide me

Here is the structure looks like:

```
<div class="page_sp">
    <a class="pagecl" href="">prevpage</a> 
    <a class="page" href="">1</a> 
    <a class="page" href="">2</a> 
    ....
    <a class="page" href="">9</a> 
    <a class="page" href="">10</a> 
    <a class="pagecl" href="www.test.com?p=2">nextpage</a> 
    <span class="page_sp">1/20 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nth-of-type` would not work with a `class` name, see [css3 nth of type restricted to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class).

Instead, you may search for `a` with `nextpage` text:

```
>>> response.css("div.page_sp > a:contains('nextpage')::attr(href)").extract()
[u'www.test.com?p=2']
```

Answer (score -1):

Very poor code!!!
Are you just trying to fetch the next page link?
Use this:

```
$("a:last-of-type").attr("href");
```

Although, I must say, there are better ways to do this and you should use other selectors. But well, you didn't give us any contexts so here it is!!!