# CSS: nth-child works bad when adding new elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm making a photo gallery, and I have four elements per row.

[Demo](http://senk.ch/bittersweet/archive.php)

I have a margin for the space between images.

```
.picDesc {
   float: left;
   margin:0 1% 1% 0; /*  <--- this */
   width: 24.2%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Obviously I don't need the margin for the last div on the right.

So I use nth-child for remove the margin of the fourth div.

```
.picDesc:nth-child(4n+4){
    margin:0 0% 1% 0;
}
```

And works!

But when I click on an album, for example "Altro", and show the pics of this album, the margins are wrong how you can see.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: not sure it is what want but try .picDesc:nth-child(4n+1),

Comment: it will not count based on .picDesc. It will count on div.

Comment: Altering demo class .picDesc:nth-of-type(4n+4) to .picDesc:nth-of-type(4n+1) makes photo alignemnts looks better.

Comment: Plase mark the correct answer for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of this element:

```
<div class="albumDesc"><a href="archive.php">Albums</a><p></p></div>
<!-- (Temporarily remove it and see for yourself) -->
```

Which `nth-child()` acknowledges.

Place your your `<div class="picDesc">` elements in their own container and then narrow the `nth-child()` scope.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="albumDesc"><a href="archive.php">Albums</a><p></p></div>
<div class="picDescCont">
    <div class="picDesc">..</div>
    <div class="picDesc">..</div>
    ....
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.picDescCont .picDesc:nth-child(4n+4){
    margin:0 0% 1% 0;
}
```

Note: `.picDesc:nth-child(4n+4)` means every *n* element that has the class `.picDesc`, not every *n* element of the elements that have the class `.picDesc`.

Comment: I also suggest to add `nth-child(4n)` which will give you the needed result if you want to clear margin in every last item.

Comment: You are completly right!

I'm feeling so stupid, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Gabriele No worries! Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because **`nth-of-type` if for the same types**. So, the class `albumDesc` is the first div.

Unfortunately `nth-of-class` doens't exist.

You can change the `albumDesc` to a title header, so is more semantic and don't need group the divs.

```
<h1 class="albumDesc"><a href="archive.php">Albums</a></h1>
```

You must read the [css3 nth of type restricted to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class).