# Select even elements of a class independently from their type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have elements of a given `secondclass` with grey background and I would like only even elements of this class with a red background. I can't use `nth-child()` selector because these elements might not be the only inside parent.

I've tried the following:

```
.secondclass {
    background-color:#aaa;
}

.secondclass:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

This works fine until I put an element of the same type of `secondclass` inside parent (i.e. a div). This is reasonable, since `nth-of-type()` refers to the type not the class:

```
<div>some text</div>
<div class="secondclass"></div>
<div class="secondclass"></div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrrk82op/3/)

Is there a pure-CSS way to select only even elements of `secondclass` subset, independently from their type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 nth of type restricted to class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make 2 classes for the even and uneven and just assign these classes where it is necessary? Otherwise trying to figure out how to make a logic check within CSS seems a very long detour to the same result.

The class for "even" elements will have red background and "uneven" will have grey background.

```
.uneven {
    background-color:#aaa;
}

.even {
    background-color:red;
}
```

And the divs:

```
<div>some text</div>
<div class="uneven"></div>
<div class="even"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one way which I see is use different HTML tag.
Like:

```
<div>some text</div>
<span class="secondclass"></span>
<span class="secondclass"></span>
```

Demo:

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrrk82op/5/)

But there is no pure CSS solution

Comment: This was my second choise, if no pure-css solution was feasible.