# CSS :nth-of-type selector breaks on non-matching childs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a problem with CSS :nth-of-type selector. In my code I have a list of DIVs (class "item") that should have an alternating background-color (eg. red and green). Between these items there can be some other items (class "noitem") that should **not** be matched from the background-color.

Problem is now, that the :nth-of-type rule breaks on every of these non-matching elements. that causes that you have one red item after the other...

Example HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="noitem"><h2>No Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="noitem"><h2>No Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2{
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row .item:nth-of-type(even) h2{
  background-color: red;
}

.row .item:nth-of-type(odd) h2{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Can anybody help? Running example of that can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5qnjshg7/

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 nth of type restricted to class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems impossible with CSS, unless you can change your markup and make `noitem` elements `<span>`s?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <span class="noitem"><h2>No Item</h2></span>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <span class="noitem"><h2>No Item</h2></span>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Item</h2></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The **type** in `nth-of-type` refers to the type of element (tag name, such as `div`). It does **not** mean "nth-of-something-with-exactly-the-same-classes", or "nth-of-the-selector-I-specified", which does not exist in CSS.

In other words, `.item:nth-of-type(even)` does **not** mean "an even-numbered entry in the list of all child elements with class `.item`", but rather, "an element with class `.item` which also is in an even-numbered position in the list of all child elements of that type (`div` in this case), regardless of their class or anything else".

#### One possible approach if you're stuck with the existing HTML

If you can generate different HTML, including for example new classes, or replacing the `div` on `noitem` elements with `span`s, as one answer suggested, then that is the best solution. In case you are not able to do or don't want to do that, and need to work with the existing HTML for whatever reason, this bit of JS will do the job:

```
var elts = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
for (var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
    elts[i].classList.add(i % 2 ? 'red' : 'green');
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to add javascript for this.

Comment: @MichaelTempest What is your approach then?

Comment: Simply add the classes to the DOM, its basic HTML, why use a javascript loop to get all the elements. Also if he is dynamically generating them, then it is easy to do in that format too

Comment: Well, the OP was asking why the CSS `nth-of-type` pseudo-class did not behave as he expected. The first 2/3 of my answer was answering that. As far as the bit of JS here, I'm not suggesting it is the only or optimal solution, but it's one way to deal with the situation which could be useful especially if he has no control over the generated HTML, as is sometimes the case. I've fine-tuned the wording in my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

nth-of-type matches the element to its parent, so although it is not the same selector, it is in fact the correct index relevant to its parent.