# nth-child selecting wrong element from a multi-class div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have some `div`s with 2 classess - all of them have `ticket`  class and some of them have `visible` class:

```
<div class="ticket hidden">BLA 1</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">BLA 2</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">BLA 3</div>
<div class="ticket visible">BLA 4</div>
<div class="ticket visible">BLA 5</div>
<div class="ticket visible">BLA 6</div>
<div class="ticket visible">BLA 7</div>
<div class="ticket visible">BLA 8</div>
```

When I'm adressing it with:

```
.visible:nth-child(5) {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I get BLA 5, and i want BLA 8

How can I adress specific .visible element?

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7uap9v21/1/)

Comment: would it be possible to use :last-child? o is it just a coincidence that's it's at the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nth-child doesn't respond to class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS :nth-of-type selector breaks on non-matching childs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313984/css-nth-of-type-selector-breaks-on-non-matching-childs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>`nth-child()` don´t care which class you want to check. It always count all siblings in a DOM element.</del>

<del>Maybe you want to give `:nth-of-type` a chance: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)</del>

Maybe the best solution is to use some jQuery and add another class to append the `underline` style

Comment: Ah i see. Unfortunately this sticks to html elements and not to classes. Because all your elements are `<div>`s it doesn´t work either, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 3):

`:nth-child` *further* restricts the matched elements to those that are nth child of its parent. There is no CSS selector that matches *nth element having class x*.

For the given markup, you could use the `+` combinator:

```css
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible {
  /*
   * matches .visible element with at least 4 previous .visible siblings
   */
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible {
  /*
   * matches .visible element with at least 5 previous .visible siblings
   */
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 1</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 2</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 3</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 4</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 5</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 6</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket hidden">Hidden</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 7</div>
<div class="ticket visible">Visible 8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div at the beginning of the `visible` class and give it the `nth-child` http://jsfiddle.net/7uap9v21/3/

```
<div class="visible-holder">
<div class="visible ticket">BLA 4</div>
<div class="visible ticket">BLA 5</div>
<div class="visible ticket">BLA 6</div>
<div class="visible ticket">BLA 7</div>
<div class="visible ticket">BLA 8</div>
</div>
```