# nth-child that isn't filtered

Tags: html, css

I have several elements that I want to use `nth-child` to apply a `background-color` to. The issue is that I need to be able to hide any of these elements on the fly using javascript. I thought I could keep the alternating colors by adding/removing an `allow` class, and applying `nth-child` to that, but to no avail. I have an example going in a jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tL40wz03/ 
Thanks for your help!

HTML

```
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item allow"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div.allow{
    background: gray; 
}

div:nth-child(even){
  background: orange;
}
div:not(.allow){
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Technically your code is working as intended. It's ignoring the two without allow and based on the number of divs at the even marks it is adding the color. Don't think your code isn't working just not selecting the right ones

Comment: There are a couple of related questions here on SO. Bottom line is, `nth-child` is exactly `nth-child` and applies to even children no matter what other classes or styles they might have.

Comment: @torazaburo Is that to say there is no way to do what I intend to do?

Comment: @Geohut Maybe so. Bottom line is I can't figure out how to get the effect I want. Any way I could achieve this?

Comment: @torazaburo Using 'even' and 'odd' classes I assume?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 nth of type restricted to class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need JS, something like

```
function markEven() {
    var items= document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var classes = items[i].classList;
        classes.toggle('even', classes.contains('allow') && ++count % 2);
    }
}
```

And call this every time `allow` is added to or removed from an element.

Then

```
div.item       { display: none;  background: gray;   }
div.item.allow { display: block;                     }   
div.item.even  {                 background: orange; }
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but it looks increasingly like this is the only option. Thanks.