# Refresh nth-of-type order after filtering

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, mixitup

I sort some `<li>` with MixItUp (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs) but CSS fails to apply the correct nth-of-type when the order changes (button 2 pushed). It stills use the `li.isActive:nth-of-type(3n+2)` instead of `li.isActive:nth-of-type(3n+1)`
I tried to add `.isActive` on filtered elements but it's ineffective. Is there any way to sort or refresh visible elements with  `nth-child` or  `nth-of-type` ? Thanks.

HTML

```
<ul id="mosaic">
    <li class="col-md-4 mix freelance" data-myorder="1">
        <div class="project">
            1
            <p class="card-text">
                xyz
            </p>
        </div>                        
    </li>
```

SCSS

```
#mosaic li.isActive:nth-of-type(1) .project {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}...
```

Javascript

```
$('#mosaic').mixItUp({
    callbacks: {
        onMixEnd: function(state){
            console.log(state.$show);
            state.$targets.removeClass('isActive');
            state.$show.addClass('isActive');
        }
    }
});
```

Full example on Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0d8LgsxL/

Comment: I wouldn't say the CSS is failing, but rather the selectors '-nth-child' and '-nth-of-type' do not ignore hidden elements.

Comment: That's why i tried to add .isActive class on visible elements. :)

Comment: See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10931957/4035952
 Since there is no nth-of-class, the class name does not help the CSS reduce the match set how you would like it to work.
You could potentially clone your "active" tabs to another location for proper styling, if you don't want to use JS to style them manually.

Comment: I'll try this, then. Thanks for the answer !