# CSS step over or skip alternating div class :nth-of-type or :nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to select every third (speaker) div to clear the float where content is lumped in together.

Every second div is a modal popup & it seems to conflict with nth-child or nth-of-type?

Please see example below where I have commented out the top row modal class.

```css
.custom-speakers .speaker:nth-of-type(2n+1)
{
 clear:both;
 background:#FAFAFA;
 border:1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>STEP OVER EVERY MODAL NTH-CHILD / NTH-OF-TYPE</title>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row custom-speakers">
     <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 1</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 2</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 3</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 4</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 5</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 6</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 7</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 8</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 9</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 10</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 11</h2></div>
        <!--<div class="modal fade"></div>-->
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div class="row custom-speakers">
     <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 1-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 2-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 3-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 4-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 5-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 6-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 7-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 8-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 9-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 10-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 11-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```css
.custom-speakers>div:nth-child(4n+5)
{
 clear:both;
 background:#ddd;
 border:1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>STEP OVER EVERY MODAL NTH-CHILD</title>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row custom-speakers">
     <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 1-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 2-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 3-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 4-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 5-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 6-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 7-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 8-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 9-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 10-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
        <div class="speaker col-sm-6"><h2>SPEAKER 11-2</h2></div>
        <div class="modal fade"></div>
    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with modal popup. `:nth-of-type()` only selects the nth child of its **type** (tag, element). Unfortunately, there is no CSS selector such as nth-of-class.

According to @Eduardo Wada ([css3 nth of type restricted to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class)), we can add a special class to the elements interested:

```
$(".custom-speakers .speaker").filter(function(index){
    return index % 2 == 0;
}).addClass("interested-speaker");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think I got it with CSS

.custom-speakers>div:nth-child(4n+5)
{
 clear:both;
 background:#ddd;
 border:1px solid #FFF;
}