# CSS nth-child(odd) misbehaving when having additional elements in parent

Tags: html, css

The HTML and CSS below produce that the 1st and 4th elements get the nth-child(odd) style instead of the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... elements.

If I continue and add additional elements with the class "one" they will be colored in the following pattern:

1st, 4th, 5th, 8th, ... and so on.

I am not sure why this is the behaviour, any alternatives that will actually work only with CSS?

```css
.one {
  background-color:yellow;
}

.two {
  background-color:red;
}

.one:nth-child(odd) {
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
First Paragraph of class one
</p>
<p class="one">
Second Paragraph of class one
</p>
<p class="two">
First Paragraph of class two
</p>
<p class="one">
Third Paragraph of class one
</p>
<p class="one">
Forth Paragraph of class one
</p>
```

Comment: useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10931957/3840840

Comment: @sebastianbrosch thx for that, this is the JavaScript solution which is not optimal for me because elements will be loaded dynamically to the page, and I don't want to run calculations every time something changes.

But if not solution in CSS is found, this solution will be used. so Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `.one:nth-child(odd)` to `p:nth-child(odd)` instead of using class

```css
.one {
  background-color:yellow;
}

.two {
  background-color:red;
}

p:nth-child(odd) {
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
First Paragraph of class one
</p>
<p class="one">
Second Paragraph of class one
</p>
<p class="two">
First Paragraph of class two
</p>
<p class="one">
Third Paragraph of class one
</p>
<p class="one">
Forth Paragraph of class one
</p>
```

Comment: But he *wants* to limit it to just the .one class. You're doing exactly what he *doesn't* want to do.

Comment: OP wants the pink color to be assigned in the order 1,3,5... to the elements and here it is!

Comment: @HiteshMisro I want the pink color only on the `p.one` elements. preferably using only css because elements will be loaded dynamically to the page with inifinite scroll. some elements will have the `two` class, but I want only odd elements with the `one` class to get a certain attribute.