# nth-of-type not working unless html element changed

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm being driven mad by this problem. I'm trying to target every other instance of a div with a particular class by using nth-of-type. I've gotten nth-of-type to work when the HTMl elements are changed up but not when it's just divs. It must be that I'm not understanding something right so I appreciate your help with this!

Here's an example, close to what I need (except the inner section tags should be divs):

```
.employee-group {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.employee-group:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: blue;
}
```

```
<div class="employee-group">
    <p class="employee">Odd</p>
    <p class="employee">Div</p>
</div>
<section>
    <p>Section</p>
</section>
<div class="employee-group">
    <p class="employee">Even .employee-group</p>
    <p class="employee">Works as expected, no background color</p>
</div>
<section>
    <p>Section</p>
</section>
<div class="employee-group">
    <p class="employee">Odd</p>
    <p class="employee">Div</p>
</div>
<section>
    <p>Section</p>
</section>
```

http://codepen.io/usern4me/pen/BLZjJj

And here is the scenario that I need to make work but for the life of me I can't do it:

```
.employee-group {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.employee-group:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: blue;
}
```

```
<div class="employee-group">
    <p class="employee">Odd</p>
    <p class="employee">Div</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Even</p>
    <p>Div</p>
</div>
<div class="employee-group">
    <p class="employee">Odd div</p>
    <p class="employee">But even .employee-group (shouldn't have bg color!!!)</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Even</p>
    <p>Div</p>
</div>
<div class="employee-group">
    <p class="employee">Odd</p>
    <p class="employee">Div</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Even</p>
    <p>Div</p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/usern4me/pen/YGbwEb

It seems like the nth-type-of selector is matching the class and that it's an odd div in the total amount of divs. I would expect it to just solely look at the class for the count.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this not supported with nth-of-type,filtering on class .this could be of some help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class

Comment: You're right, this was the behavior I was expecting. Thank you for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the even .employee-group issue change the `.employee-group:nth-of-type(odd)` to

```
.employee-group:nth-of-type(4n+1)
```

Explaination: Your requirement wanted to skip every other item within a odd sequence i.e. instead of (1,3,5,7,9,11....) the properties should hit (1,5,9,13....) etc. To do that we gave the parameter a formula to calculate that so what the css does is takes the index (0,1,2,3) as n for each .employee-group element and calculates where to apply the properties based on formula result which goes as

(4n+1) = target number

(4x0+1)= 1

(4x1+1)= 5

(4x2+1)= 9

(4x3+1)= 13

...and so on.

That should solve your problem i believe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: now it is considering the divs which does not have employee group

Comment: Check answer again please. Sorry i misunderstood the requirement. Answer updated. :). Instead of 'odd' as parameter. Use '4n+1'.

Comment: @Geeky If you have another question, ask a new question. Comments are meant for clarifying posts, not new threads of discussion.

Comment: @Geeky, check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107