# Tricky :nth-child selector

Tags: css

I have spent a while with solving the following problem:

I would love to wrap the "infinite" number of floated div by four in column (and different for smaller media width) by adding `clear:left` to the each fifth  element;

I made a fiddle where it works just fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/zqnkxa3h/1/

But no matter whatever I do, in the [real situation](http://staging.kybernaut.cz/cafeplechac/?product=sestav-si-salat) the layout gets broken (two last items are wrongly wrapped, when I set it back to `:nth-child(4n+1)`, it breaks a different way completely.
Is there anything I'm missing on that page? I have no idea how to fix it myself. The class is `.bundled_product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `.component-data` containers have a first child `.kbnt-items` and a second child `.min_max_items`. The last `.component-data` container is missing the `.kbnt-items` child, that's why the third child of this container is the second `.bundled_product` here.

```
<div class="component_data">
  <div class="kbnt-items">0/1</div> <!-- missing in your last component_data... -->
  <div class="min_max_items"></div>
  <div class="bundled_prodct">...</div> 
  <div class="bundled_prodct">...</div> <!-- ... that's why this one is the '4n+3' element -->
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks a lot for pointing it out. I thought should counts only `.bundled_product` class not every child within the class. How I would do that correctly? The `.kbnt-items` and `.min_max_items` are optional (and based on user settings).

Comment: As [there is no nth-of-class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10931957/3162554) and [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) won't help here either as `.kbnt-items` and `.min_max_items` are of the same type as `.bundled_product` - you could wrap your `.bundled_product`s in another div so that you can use the nth-child-selector (without the `+` part, just 4n). The products will then be the only childs of that newly created container and you don't have to care about different numbers of children.

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2raquk6x/) demonstrating the wrapper idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your last item has the class `..bundled_product:nth-child(4n+3)` which contains `clear: left`, that's why it is put in a new line.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it wasn't what I asked for (see the correct answer above you).