# nth-of-type is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply some CSS on second active class. Only two element can have active class at a time.

I have tried the following CSS selectors:

```
 .p .active:last-of-type
 .p .active:nth-of-type(2)
```

But neither of them are working. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```css
.p .active:nth-of-type(2){
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="a">The first paragraph.</div>
  <div class="a active">The second paragraph.</div>
  <div class="a active">The third paragraph.</div>
  <div class="a">The fourth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `type` in CSS property name means tag. So `:nth-of-type(2)` looks for the second `div` and check if has `class=b`.

Comment: One day we might have this https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo which would look like `.p *:nth-child(2 of .b) {background: yellow}` but not yet.

Comment: Vote for Reopen the question because in _duplicate_ topis there is anothor code and the answer there isn't valid for this topic.

Comment: @panther There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class which is closed as a duplicate of the target question here.

Comment: @TylerH: from accepted answer: '_You will probably have to add a new class to every third .module manually._'... eh? :-) I think it's possible without adding new classes. Any else _solutions_?

Comment: @panther Feel free to go to the target question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector and add that solution if it does not exist already.

Comment: @TylerH: ok, so be please so kind and show me the code for this answer which is meant in your _duplicate_ topic. Good luck friend. Try it without JavaScript (isn't needed, isn't in tags, ...) and color me the second `.b` element from this question (not always the third `.a` or third `div`).

Comment: @panther I'm confused... you are saying this question about how to do something with CSS isn't a duplicate because you... can't do it without JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS hasn't *native* tools how to do that. A little hackish code could be

```css
.p .b ~ .b {background: red;} /* set properties to 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... .b elements */
.p .b ~ .b ~ .b {background: none;}  /* reset properties to 3rd, 4th, ... .b elements */
```

```html
<div class="p">
    <div class="a">The first paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a b">The second paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a b">The third paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a">The fourth paragraph.</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="p">
    <div class="a">The first paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a b">The second paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a b">The third paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a b">The fourth paragraph.</div>
    <div class="a">The fifth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your code?

Comment: @PlanetHackers: I've added a comments into CSS. The first CSS line set `background: red` to `2, 3, 4, ...xth .b` elements. The second line just reset these rules to default (the same as the first .b has).

Comment: Of course, this falls over if you have `.a {background: #aaa}`  and expect all future instances of .b to still pick that up. But there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: @PlanetHackers: for better understanding I've create you another fiddle... maybe helps you. https://jsfiddle.net/8pdpfkke/

Comment: @AndrewBone: sure, when `.a` has different styles from `.b` the question would be changed and solution is possible, but not exactly this way (but the principle stays the same). You can find second `.b` and if there is `.a` too, set another color. Or find second single `.b`... Everything is possible :-)