# Dojo 1.7 pseudo selector not working well?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am just trying to retrieve a text input element, but the [pseudo selector 'first-of-type'](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html#standard-css3-selectors) seems not working. Ex:

```
//... requires dojo/query
var fields = query('input[type="text"]', form);// works well
var fields = query('input[type="text"]:first-of-type', form);// returns empty array :(
```

Then a another related question :
what is the syntax to query the dom with multiple attr values : retrieve input with attr type = "text" AND attr name = "the-name" ??
Thank you for any help.

Comment: consider including the html that you're trying to select with that selector and what is first-of-type supposed to select.

Answer (score 0):

I trying to reproduce your issue, **and for me seems works fine**. I suppose you are making a query to find a input inside to form. There is my code. I guess you are using **1.7.x**

[Check the code](http://jsfiddle.net/3AdMg/7/)

Comment: thank you for the fiddle, so here is mine : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qa4Z5/) , as you can see the pseudo first-of-type returns an empty array. The point is that I have one other node before my input text...so I am not understanding the use of this pseudo. I thought if I had many input text, I'll be able to retrieve the first one of that type. I just have to use fields[0]...In fact I made a confusion with attribute 'type' and 'first-of-type' tag type...

Comment: I think the problem is pseudo class not allow attributes 
About Pseudo-classes
[http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html#pseudo]
Another ask related with your question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name]