# DIV First-Of-Type doesn't work after div with clear:both

Tags: html, css

My problem is that the first DIV in my box should be :first-of-type, but actually it's not.

It happens after inserting

```
<div class="horizontal_line"></div>
```

after first

```
<div class="field_container">
     <div class="field_icon"></div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse luctus eget lectus at convallis.</p>
</div>
```

the icon just dissappears and whole dive falls down, losing it's first-of-type pseudoclass.

I'd like it to look like this: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jialh.png)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfYUc/2/) of my page

Common style for all boxes, and style for the first one

```
.field_container
    {
    width: 216px;
    margin-left: 28px; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    }
.field_container .field_icon
    {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
.field_container:first-of-type
    {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
.field_container:first-of-type .field_icon
    {
    background-image: url('images/front_end.png');
    width: 83px;
    }
```

and style of the horizontal line, which causes the problem

```
.horizontal_line
    {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
    height: 1px;
    clear: both;
    background: #1C788B;
    }
```

Comment: Post all the relevant HTML/CSS here and a jsFiddle replicating the problem please.

Comment: The point of a fiddle is to present a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). Just copy/pasting your entire website [is not practical nor welcome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). If you want help, size your problem down to something we can help with - our time is also expensive.

Comment: It's done. Sorry guys. I'm asking here for the very fist time and i must admit, that i didn't read FAQ or anything like that, so forgive me. I've updated jsFidle and reduced code.

Comment: It's because it's your first time that we take the time and effort to point it out in a friendly way  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first-of-type` is for the first type of that element (`p`, `div`, etc). You cannot use this with a class/id. The reason it works until you add the `horizonal_line` div is because you're selecting the first element of that kind (`div`), so adding the `horizontal_line` `div` makes it the *first type of that element*.

- [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

In your case, you can use `:nth-child` instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```
.field_container div:first-of-type {
    /* Will select the first div in .field_container */
}
.field_container {
    /* set no left margin */
}
.field_container + .field_container {
    /* set left margin on adjacent .field_container */
    margin-left: 28px;
}
.field_container:nth-child(2) .field_icon {
    /* change the icon for each nth-child() */
}
```

Comment: but the whole thing works fine until i insert horizontal_line before the div with the boxes.

Comment: I updated my answer to help explain a bit more clearly.