# :first-child selector doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to give more width to the first `<article class="type-reviews">` element, so I've tried:

```
/*this is what I had previously and works right*/
#show-reviews .type-reviews {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 31%;  
    margin-right: 2% !important;
    padding: 0px; 
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

#### NEW RULE:

```
/*this is what I've added to change the first element width*/
#show-reviews .type-reviews:first-child {
    width: 50% !important;  
}
```

but the new CSS doesn't change anything. Even inspecting with Firebug seems that the rule is not applied to the first element.

The HTML is the next:

```
...
<div id="show-reviews">
    <div id="banner-lateral">...</div>
    <article id="post-300" class="post-300 type-reviews status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail">...</article>
    <article id="post-222" class="post-222 type-reviews status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail">...</article>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yes because without the HTML there so much we can do... Need your HTML.

Comment: Try `:first-of-type` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `.type-reviews` *isn't* the first child, your `div` element is. It is the first `article` element, however, therefore you can use `:first-of-type`:

```css
#show-reviews .type-reviews:first-of-type {
    width: 50%;  
}
```

Also you really don't need to use `!important` here, as your new selector has higher specificity than your old one.

For reference:

```
<div id="show-reviews">
    <div ...>...</div>            <!-- First child, first of type (div) -->
    <article ...>...</article>    <!-- Second child, first of type (article) -->
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the html I cannot be sure but I gues there might be a different element that is the first child in the container, like this:

```
<div id="show-reviews">
    <span>some other element</span>
    <div class="type-reviews">This is not the first child</div>
    <div class="type-reviews">This is another..</div>
</div>
```

Either make sure no other element is before the element you want or consider using the [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) selector instead.

Answer (score 1):

FROM [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

> The `:first-of-type` selector matches every element that is the first
>   child, of a particular type, of its parent.
>
> This is the same as :nth-of-type(1).

`:first-of-type` was introduced in CSS Selectors Module 3, which means old versions of browsers do not support it. However, modern browser support is impeccable, and the new pseudo-selectors are widely used in production environments

From [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

> No, the :first-of-type pseudo-class selects the first element of its
>   type (div, p, etc). Using a class selector (or a type selector) with
>   that pseudo-class means to select an element if it has the given class
>   (or is of the given type) and is the first of its type among its
>   siblings.
>
> Unfortunately, CSS doesn't provide a :first-of-class selector that
>   only chooses the first occurrence of a class. As a workaround, you can
>   use something like this:
>
> ```
> .myclass1 { color: red; }
> .myclass1 ~ .myclass1 { color: /* default, or inherited from parent div */; }
>   [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp.
> ```

So you must use

```
#show-reviews .type-reviews ~ .type-reviews{
     width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: @ManoloSalsas this is not the repeated answer mate, that answer just worked please read my answer now..!!

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: tell me if this is the repeated answer or just the right answer ?

Comment: Now it is not a repeated answer. Thanks :) Anyway, @JamesDonelly answer works perfect for my case.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should work in chrome and Firefox both.it might be possible other part of CSS is overriding your rules