# How to select only for the first of divs with equal names?

Tags: html, css, select

How to select only for the first of many divs with equal names with CSS? For example i have this:

```
<div class="div">dsdas</div>
<div class="div">123</div>
<div class="div">73</div>
<div class="div">63</div>
<div class="div">53</div>
<div class="div">45</div>
```

How to select only the first div(with class "div")?

Comment: Look at this, there'S shown how you can solve it in css.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6447072/2529682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pseudo-selector :nth-of-type(). To select the first element with the class "div", do it like this:

```
.div:nth-of-type(1) {

}
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vJ9YS/1)**

Comment: Thanks that it. It should be like this .div:nth-of-type(1){
margin-left:0px;
}

Comment: That will select the first div, not the first div that is a member of a particular class.

Comment: Re edit: `:nth-of-type` always selects based on **type**, it doesn't select the first thing that matches the previous part of the selector.

Comment: @Quentin You're right this will only work with type, a workaround for use with class can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name/6447072#6447072)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.div:nth-of-type(1)
{
    //add style here
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/7yY6j/)

Comment: That will select the first div if it is a member of the class, not the first div that is a member of a particular class.

Answer (score -1):

using jquery :

```
var firstDiv = $('.div').first();
```

Documentation http://api.jquery.com/first/

or like this:

```
var firstDiv = $('.div:first');
```

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: The question is tagged `css`, not `javascript`.

Comment: Question is tagged under CSS category and we can achieve this via css easily.