# How does css3 count :nth-of-type items?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having issues with clearing margins using `:nth-of-type(3n+3)`. If I use any div or anything it upsets the counting of items. Any ideas as to why this might be happening and what I can do to work around it?

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7G4e/

CSS

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
    /* overflow acts the same as clear */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
div.row{
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.one-of-three{
    width:200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:50px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.one-of-three:nth-of-type(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="one-of-three">one-of-three</div>
<div class="one-of-three">one-of-three</div>
<div class="one-of-three">one-of-three</div>

<div class="clear">div divider</div>
<!-- <div>blank div does the same thing - just not as visible for debugging</div> -->

<div class="one-of-three">one-of-three</div>
<div class="one-of-three">one-of-three</div>
<div class="one-of-three">one-of-three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:nth-of-type` pseudo class is meant for elements ***types*** - not classes. Since all of your elements are `div`s, there is no distinction between them because the classes are disregarded. One possible work-around would be to change the `.clear` element from a `div` to a `span`.

```
<span class="clear">rogue div divider</span>
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcsJ5/)

```
.clear{
    display:block;
    clear: both;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Just change the element's display to `block` in order to make it behave as a `div` element.

Comment: So you're saying that even if I targeted 'div.one-of-three:nth-of-type(3n+3)' that it still wouldn't work because they're all divs?

Comment: @michael Correct. You may be interested in [this relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name). It may be explained better there.

Comment: That's strange because if I add another item like: "div.one-of-four:nth-of-type(4n+4)" they work as well. Distinct and separate from the others. So there apparently is some attention paid to classes, I'm just not sure how much they get.

Comment: @michael: Every simple selector applies, but each one is processed independently of all the others and the results AND'd together - if an element matches every one of them, then you have a match. div.one-of-four:nth-of-type(4n+4) matches an element that happens to match all of these conditions: 1) is a div 2) has a class called "one-of-four" 3) is :nth-of-type(4n+4). The class selector (and any other simple selector) is not considered by :nth-of-type() itself, but it is considered when matching the entire selector.