# Style first element with class

Tags: html, css, less

Is there a way to style only the first element with a specific class? The :first-child psuedo selector seems to only work on tags.

EDIT: Not all classes have the same parent element so :first-child isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no first-of-class selector.

See BoltClock's answer ([CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name))

There is a work around but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
<div>
    <p class="blue">1st</p>
    <div class="blue">2nd</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="blue">3rd</p>
    <div class="blue">4th</div>
</div>
```

So this will make only the first element as blue

Also check [:first-child pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-child)

> The :first-child pseudo-class matches an element that is the first
>   child element of some other element.

Answer (score 0):

`.class-name:nth-of-type(1)`

This should style what you want

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rSLLP/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work  `.classNamep:first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check your class name. A typo could happen.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CR9zv/). It shows you that `:first-child` works even with class selectors. :)

Code:

```
<span class="spana">first</span>
<span class="spana">second</span>

.spana:first-child {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `nth-child()` pseudo class selector is a good approach, this is supported in all major browsers, including IE9+.

Here is the example HTML:

```
<div class="blue">Will be blue</div>    
<div class="blue">Will not be blue</div>
<div class="blue">Will not be blue</div>
<div class="blue">Will not be blue</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.blue:nth-child(1) {
    color: blue;
}
```

This will select the first div of class name `blue`. Bare in mind that the first iteration is selected by passing `1` into the pseudo class, not `0` like arrays for example.

There are also other key features of the `nth-child()` pseudo class; as well as passing in numbers like I have shown previously, the pseudo class also supports key words such as `even` or `odd` like so.

```
//Applies styling to every even instance of the class .blue 
.blue:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}

//Applies styling to every odd instance of the class .blue 
.blue:nth-child(odd) {
    color: blue;
}
```

This can also be taken further; a formula can be expressed as to exactly which elements the styling is to be applied to.
The formula is expressed `an+b`, where a is the frequency of the elements to select, and b is the offset. So the formula `3n+4` will apply styling to the fourth element, and every third element beyond that. (4, 7, 10, 13, 16, etc...). Below is an example of how this can be applied.

```
//Style every 6th instance of the class .blue, starting with the second element. (2, 8, 14, 20, 26).
.blue:nth-child(6n+2) {
    color: blue;
}
```

If no offset is required then simply pass in the same formula as before, dropping the offset at the end; passing in `4n` is an example of this.

I hope this helps, I feel that this pseudo class is very powerful, and equally under rated by a lot of people.