# Weirdest css bug. Unable to get the first element

Tags: css, css-selectors

The task is very short and simple:

There are 4 div elements with class "mdf_filter_section" and I need to get the first one with CSS only (NO JS and NO jQuery).

Neither ":first-child, :nth-child(1), :first-of-type, :nth-of-type(1)" works. Before you give me an answer please check and try it yourself [on my demo](http://goo.gl/HEaFcL) in developer tool of your browser.

Demo Link: http://goo.gl/HEaFcL

Comment: Issues like these usually stem from improperly closed elements in your DOM. CSS doesn't know where things start and stop. There's quite a lot of code to dig through, but this is where I'd look.

Comment: @fontophilic thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. But even when I removed underscores and spaces at the end of the class name - it didn't solve the issue. I agree that there's a lot of code, but we can use "console" tool to find css3 selectors quickly using jquery to debug our css code like this: jQuery('.mdf_filter_section'). So I don't understand why jQuery('.mdf_filter_section:first-of-type') or jQuery('.mdf_filter_section:nth-of-type(1)') doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (shouldn't) use underscores for css class names.

Also, `first-child` actually gets the element only if it is the first child of its parent, which it is not in this case.

One way to get the div you want is:

```
.mdf_widget_form > div:nth-of-type(2){}
```

also:

```
.mdf_filter_section.business{}
```

(but don't use underscores)

EDIT: Another solution (detailed explanation in the link in my comment)

```
.mdf_filter_section {background: red;}
.mdf_filter_section ~ .mdf_filter_section {background: transparent;}
```

This would make all classes selected have a red background, then overwrite all following siblings to transparent background, this works pretty well if you don't have too many css properties to add to the first class. (`transparent` could also be `inherit` or similar)

Comment: WOW, It's fantastic! I typed in console jQuery('.mdf_widget_form > div:nth-of-type(2)') and it worked like a charm! I can't believe! I've tested so many variants but nothing works. Thank you SO MUCH! Do you have any suggestions why jQuery('.mdf_filter_section:first-of-type') or jQuery('.mdf_filter_section:nth-of-type(1)') won't work? I think it's logical to use these examples, I was sure they should work, but I can't understand why my code is non-working. Also thank you for your advice with underscores. I won't use it in future.

Comment: P.s: don't pay any attention at jQuery in my previous comment; I just used it as an example to see a fast result of code in debugger.

Comment: I'm glad it works like you wanted! Have a look at this answer, it's nicely detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name

Comment: Why shouldn't people use underscores in their css class name? As far as I know there is nothing wrong with using underscores in class names