# Select the first-of-type div in a list that all have a data-attribute for the state it's associated with

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a dynamically created list of elements that are job's in a particular state. There can be more then one job per state and I'm trying to select the first one of each state, but not just the first one in this huge list. For example:

```
<section class="careers">
<div data-state="career-illinois">...</div>
<div data-state="career-illinois">...</div>
<div data-state="career-illinois">...</div>
<div data-state="career-michigan">...</div>
<div data-state="career-michigan">...</div>
<div data-state="career-michigan">...</div>
<div data-state="career-ohio">...</div>
<div data-state="career-ohio">...</div>
</section>
```

I'd like to (with js or css) select just the first state of each group.
I was hoping to achieve this with:

```
.careers div[class*="career-"]:nth-of-type(1) h2 {
  color: #636467;
}
```

But that didn't work. I've tried a couple ways to target it with jQuery but no luck.Not even sure if this is possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name for why you can't do it that way and for a work-around.

Comment: And another issue is that you're selecting a class when the elements don't have one; they have a custom data attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to loop over the divs and keep track whether you've already seen a div with that data attribute

```js
var jobs = [];
$('section.careers div').each(function () {
    if ($.inArray($(this).data('state'), jobs) === -1) { // an element with this data attribute hasn't been encountered yet
        jobs.push($(this).data('state')); // Add the data attribute to our tracking array
        $(this).addClass('first')
    }
})
```

```css
.first {
    color: #636467;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="careers">
    <div data-state="career-illinois">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-illinois">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-illinois">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-michigan">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-michigan">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-michigan">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-ohio">...</div>
    <div data-state="career-ohio">...</div>
</section>
```

or not:

Comment: Yea I'm liking that. Originally I found a work around by wrapping each group of div's in a separate span, for targeting. But I had to keep it collapsed to keep my layout, which felt gross.