# Weird behaviour of CSS nth-of-type

Tags: html, css

I use CSS nth-of-type(even) for sorting divs. Normally it is working fine, but when I make AJAX request and put new HTML div after another one, selector starts working weird.

```
.row > .cd-timeline-block-sort:nth-of-type(even) > .cd-timeline-content {
  float: right;
}
```

[image: Printscreen of timeline (before)]

```
<div class="cd-timeline-block cd-timeline-block-sort" data-event-id="284">
<div class="cd-timeline-block cd-timeline-block-sort" data-event-id="268">
<div class="cd-timeline-block cd-timeline-block-sort" data-event-id="282">
```

and after AJAX request:

[image: Printscreen of timeline (after)]

```
<!-- 1 --><div class="cd-timeline-block cd-timeline-block-sort" data-event-id="284">
<!-- 2 --><div class="cd-timeline-block" data-event-id="268" style="display: none;">
<!-- 3 --><div class="cd-timeline-block cd-timeline-block-sort eventForm" id="eventEditForm" style="display: block;">
<!-- 4 --><div class="cd-timeline-block cd-timeline-block-sort" data-event-id="282">
```

In my second example are 4 divs and 3 of them with class .cd-timeline-block-sort . I need put (1) on left, (3) on right and (4) on left side.

Comment: could you post relevant html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you want an *"nth-class"* pseudo selector [which does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6447045/87015). Since you are using JavaScript I suggest these workarounds:

1. Either remove the unwanted element from DOM
2. If this is not possible then change the tag name of the unwanted element to something else:

```
(1st div) div.cd-timeline-block.cd-timeline-block-sort
(1st del) del.cd-timeline-block
(2nd div) div.cd-timeline-block.cd-timeline-block-sort
(3rd div) div.cd-timeline-block.cd-timeline-block-sort
```

And the CSS would be:

```css
.row > div:nth-of-type(even) { }
.row > del                   { display: block; }
```

3. Another solution is to group your elements differently:

```
(1st div) div.group
              .cd-timeline-block.cd-timeline-block-sort
(2nd div) div.group
              .cd-timeline-block
              .cd-timeline-block.cd-timeline-block-sort
(3rd div) div.group
              .cd-timeline-block.cd-timeline-block-sort
```

And the CSS:

```css
.row > div:nth-of-type(even) { }
```

Comment: That looks fine! I can't remove the unwanted element.. But is it fine when I use non-existent tag name?

Comment: This question explains the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name. I have posted three workarounds. The second one uses [`del`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/del.html) tag which is a valid HTML tag (but you can use span or something else). I recommend the third one.

Answer (score 0):

You could find element you need with JQuery.

```
// 3rd element with class "cd-timeline-block-sort"
var $block = $('.cd-timeline-block-sort').eq(2);
// Check, whether we found it
if (typeof($block) != 'undefined') {
   // Set CSS styles you need
   $block.css('float', 'right');
}
```

You could write more complex logic if you need.