# How do I select this Div with CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="one">
    <div> </div>
    <div class="three"> </div>
    <div class="four"> </div>

</div>
<div class="one">
    <div> </div>
    <div class="three"> </div>
    <div class="four"> </div>
</div>
<div class="one">
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
</div>
```

I would like to select the first div with class four, I dont want to select any other div with class four, only the very first one.

How do I accomplish that with CSS?

Comment: in css you can't because you're using classes. If you want to select only the first one I suggest you use Ids instead or Javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simply with `first-child`. You would call your class + `first-child` then the div. Telling it you only want the first instance of the class you called.

`one:first-child .four` says you only want the `four` class of the first `one` class.

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dyow6k7/1/).

```
.one:first-child .four{
  /* Your code here...*/
}
```

Comment: Not to me, what browser are you using? Edit, checked safari, firefox, chrome and opera. The 2nd one is still green to me.

Comment: chrome, latest version, just checked again. that's really weird hmm

Answer (score 3):

The most suitable way to select it is the first snippet following.
But there can be many ways to select it.

```css
.one:nth-of-type(1) > .four{
   color: red;
   background: pink;
}
```

```html
    <div class="one">
        <div> First div 1st Child</div>
        <div class="three">First div 2nd child</div>
        <div class="four">First div 3rd Child </div>

    </div>
    <div class="one">
        <div>2nd div first child </div>
        <div class="three">2nd div 2nd child</div>
        <div class="four">2nd div 3rd child </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
        <div> </div>
        <div> </div>
    </div>
```

```css
div:first-of-type > .four{
  color: red;  
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div> First div 1st Child</div>
    <div class="three">First div 2nd child</div>
    <div class="four">First div 3rd Child </div>

</div>
<div class="one">
    <div>2nd div first child </div>
    <div class="three">2nd div 2nd child</div>
    <div class="four">2nd div 3rd child </div>
</div>
<div class="one">
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to define them uniquely. Grabbing class "one" refines the scope to all elements whose class="one".

If you want specifically that item you can identify it with an "id" instead of a class. id="four" or something unique.

ID's are generally meant for allowing for individual access, while class is generally meant for grouping elements to change all at once. You may use both attributes on the same element.

Comment: When the divs are generated by a loop the insert of an id is one more step. Better do it with full css techniques.

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1nmem20u/1/)

This can be done using the `:first-child` selector as below

**CSS**

```
.one:first-child >.four {
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

You can target that div using `.one:first-child >.four`