# How select nth-of-type from multiple classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've this HTML code:

```
<div class="products-wrap">
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="clearfix-sm"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="clearfix-lg"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="clearfix-sm"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="clearfix-lg"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  ...etc
</div>
```

I would like to select with CSS only 3rd divs with .product-item classes. My problem is, that :nth-of-type(3n+0) counts with all divs, so the 3rd .product-item skip.

I've tried

```
.product-wrap > .product-item:nth-of-type(3n+0) {
  ...
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Similar question (maybe duplicate) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name/6447072

Comment: TL;DR: based on the responses from duplicate questions, it cannot be done with only CSS.

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.product-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-wrap">
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
  <div class="product-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. This is not an answer to the OP's question