# How to style for first class css

Tags: jquery, css

I have `class="social"` in a HTML block like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="social">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="social">Instagram</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="social">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I style the first element with `class="social"`. I've tried using different ways but it did not work as expected. More better if using only CSS.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery but i'm not aware of a way to make this work with just CSS as no `:first-of-class` exists

```js
$('a.social').eq(0).addClass('first');
```

```css
.social.first {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="social">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="social">Instagram</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="social">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If there is no solution with css, I will use your way. Thank you so much.

Comment: You could use the nth-of-type css selector. it would be something like .social:nth-of-type(1)

Comment: you can 't use `:nth-of-type` to select a number of a class.