# BeautifulSoup nth-of-type returns empty list. Soup.select()[n -1] returns the elements. Why?

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries,_2004)

My Soup selector is:

```
test = soup.select('#bodyContent > #mw-content-text > table.wikitable:nth-of-type(4)')
```

This should return the 4th child table of #cmw-content-text.

But it's returning an empty list.

But if I query:

```
test = soup.select('#bodyContent > #mw-content-text > table.wikitable')[3]
```

I do get the same selector.

What am I missing in my implementation?

Comment: Perhaps the fourth `#mw-content-text > table` is not a `.wikitable`. :nth-of-type() isn't equivalent to an indexer.

Comment: It is. Otherwise it wouldn't be available in the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is occurring because you can't use `nth-of-type()` with a classed tag, it can only be used on a **type** of element like this: `table:nth-of-type(4)`. For this particular instance

```
test = soup.select('#bodyContent > #mw-content-text > table.wikitable:nth-of-type(4)')
```

isn't possible, so you should use the workaround you suggested in your question

```
test = soup.select('#bodyContent > #mw-content-text > table.wikitable')[3]
```

Also check out [this great question and subsequent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name) about using `:nth-of-type()` in CSS3.