# Fetching lawyer details from multiple links using bs4 in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am an absolute beginner to Web Scraping using Python and just knowing very little about programming i Python. I am just trying to extract the information of the lawyers in the Tennesse location. In the webpage ,there are multiple links, within which there are further more links about the categories of lawyers and within those are the lawyers details.

I have already extracted the links of the various city into a list and have also extracted the various categories of lawyers available in each of the city links . Now I am trying to fetch each of the profile link of the lawyers under each category of every city from where I will retrieve the details of the lawyers. But empty list is being returned . What can be done . If possible suggest.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/tennessee/', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

cities = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#browse_view a')]
for c in cities:
    r=requests.get(c)
    s1=bs(r.content,'lxml')
    categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns:nth-of-type(2) a')]
    #print(categories)
    for c1 in categories:
        r1=requests.get(c1)
        s2=bs(r1.content,'lxml')
        lawyers = [item['href'] for item in s2.select('.directory_profile a')]
        print(lawyers)
```

"I expected the output to be with the links of each of the profile of the lawyers of each category, but it is returning empty list."

"`[][][][][][][]`"

Comment: Yes I have separately printed the cities and categories list and it is printing the list correctly.

Comment: `categories ` is returned empty

Comment: if you remove nth of type it works, take a look at that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already at the level of `a` tag when using the class selector which is your first issue.

I use a different selector below and test for urls which disguise the fact they are for the same lawyer. I separate into end urls so I can use set to remove duplicates.

I use Session for efficiency of re-using connection. I add the lawyers profiles to a list and flatten list via set comprehension to remove any duplicates.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get('https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/tennessee/', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
    cities = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#browse_view a')]
    for c in cities:
        r = s.get(c)
        s1 = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns:nth-of-type(2) a')]
        for c1 in categories:
            r1 = s.get(c1)
            s2 = bs(r1.content,'lxml')
            lawyers = [item['href'].split('*')[1] if '*' in item['href'] else item['href'] for item in s2.select('.indigo_text .directory_profile')]
            final.append(lawyers)
final_list = {item for sublist in final for item in sublist}
```

Comment: Okay I have done that but then also along with the profile links, other links such as findlaw.com and other links are being extracted whereas I just need the profile links.

Comment: I have done as you stated by using the set, final_list but while printing the set final_list it is returning nothing.

Comment: Please see the edit I have made on your code. I am trying to fetch the names, practice areas, address and the farm name of each of the lawyers but it is not returning any excel sheet.

Comment: Hi, I rejected the edit as it would harm the solution. This request should be asked as a new question and include your attempts to amend there. Remember at the end you are just working with a list of urls not the content at those urls so you would need a loop over those where you request info from those urls.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for that. Did not knew it.

Comment: No worries at all :-)

Comment: I have posted a new question with my query: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508004/fetching-lawyers-details-from-a-set-of-urls-using-bs4-in-python). If possible see the question and suggest.

Answer (score 1):

From another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846384/beautifulsoup-nth-of-type-returns-empty-list-soup-selectn-1-returns-the-el):

> This is occurring because you can't use nth-of-type() with a classed tag, it can only be used on a tag like this: table:nth-of-type(4).

Your `categories` variable is returning an empty list because of that.

The workaround is given in the same post:

```py
categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns a')][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/tennessee/', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

cities = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#browse_view a')]
for c in cities:
    r=requests.get(c)
    s1=bs(r.content,'lxml')
    categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns:nth-of-type(2) a')]
    #print(categories)
    for c1 in categories:
        r1=requests.get(c1)
        s2=bs(r1.content,'lxml')
        lawyers = [item['href'] for item in s2.select('#lawyer_0_main a')]
        print(lawyers)
```

"It is printing not only the profile links but also the about and other associated links which is not required. I just want the profile links of the lawyers."

"The out put is displayed as"

```
"`['https://profiles.superlawyers.com/tennessee/alamo/lawyer/jim-emison/c99a7c4f-3a42-4953-9260-3750f46ed4bd.html', 'https://www.superlawyers.com/about/selection_process.html']
['https://profiles.superlawyers.com/tennessee/alamo/lawyer/jim-emison/c99a7c4f-3a42-4953-9260-3750f46ed4bd.html', 'https://www.superlawyers.com/about/selection_process.html']
['https://profiles.superlawyers.com/tennessee/alamo/lawyer/jim-emison/c99a7c4f-3a42-4953-9260-3750f46ed4bd.html', 'https://www.superlawyers.com/about/selection_process.html']`"
```