# Fetching Lawyers details from a set of urls using bs4 in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am an absolute beginner to Web Scraping using Python and know very little about programming in Python. I am just trying to extract the information of the lawyers in the Tennessee location. In the webpage, there are multiple links, within which there are further links to the categories of lawyers, and within those are the lawyers' details.

I have already extracted the links of the various cities into a list and have also extracted the various categories of lawyers available in each of the cities' links. The profile links have also been fetched and stored as a set. Now I am trying to fetch each lawyer's name, address, firm name and practice area and store it as an .xls file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

final=[]
records=[]
with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get('https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/tennessee/', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

    cities = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#browse_view a')]
    for c in cities:
        r=s.get(c)
        s1=bs(r.content,'lxml')
        categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns:nth-of-type(2) a')]
        for c1 in categories:
            r1=s.get(c1)
            s2=bs(r1.content,'lxml')
            lawyers = [item['href'].split('*')[1] if '*' in item['href'] else item['href'] for item in
                       s2.select('.indigo_text .directory_profile')]
            final.append(lawyers)
final_list={item for sublist in final for item in sublist}
for i in final_list:
    r2 = s.get(i)
    s3 = bs(r2.content, 'lxml')
    name = s3.find('h2').text.strip()
    add = s3.find("div").text.strip()
    f_name = s3.find("a").text.strip()
    p_area = s3.find('ul',{"class":"basic_profile aag_data_value"}).find('li').text.strip()
    records.append({'Names': name, 'Address': add, 'Firm Name': f_name,'Practice Area':p_area})
df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Address','Firm Name','Practice Areas'])
df=df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\lawyers.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

I expected to get a .xls file, but nothing is returned as the execution is going on. It does not terminate until I force stop, and no .xls file is made.

Comment: farm meaning law farm in which the lawyer practices.

Comment: Sorry spelling mistake actually law firm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract those details by visiting each lawyer's page and using the appropriate selectors. Something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

records = []
final = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get('https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/tennessee/', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
    cities = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#browse_view a')]
    for c in cities:
        r = s.get(c)
        s1 = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns:nth-of-type(2) a')]
        for c1 in categories:
            r1 = s.get(c1)
            s2 = bs(r1.content,'lxml')
            lawyers = [item['href'].split('*')[1] if '*' in item['href'] else item['href'] for item in s2.select('.indigo_text .directory_profile')]
            final.append(lawyers)
    final_list = {item for sublist in final for item in sublist}
    for link in final_list:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        name = soup.select_one('#lawyer_name').text
        firm = soup.select_one('#firm_profile_page').text
        address = ' '.join([string for string in soup.select_one('#poap_postal_addr_block').stripped_strings][1:])
        practices = ' '.join([item.text for item in soup.select('#pa_list li')])
        row = [name, firm, address, practices]
        records.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns = ['Name', 'Firm', 'Address', 'Practices'])
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Lawyers.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: Okay, but altogether there are large number of lawyers, for each it has to be searched separately?

Comment: yes unless there is another source? You could look to parallize or use asyncio to speed things up.

Comment: I might be asking a wrong question but if the final_list set contains link we are iterating over those links and storing it's content, then why will it not let us to fetch the name,address, firm name,practice areas from that content on each iteration.?

Comment: I am assuming that practice areas are listed at the level of the profile which is what my code is visting in the last loop at the bottom.

Comment: Here are all the results: https://tmpfiles.org/download/19959/Lawyers.csv

Comment: What changes did you made? If possible suggest.

Comment: I inspected the page html of one of the profile links in the browser and worked out which selectors would give me the content you asked for. I assumed, as these pages seem regular in structure, that these would hold across all profiles. I ran the code and inspected the results.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same process but not getting any .xls file. You have passed a single individual lawyer's link, then how the other links are getting iterated and contents are extracted from it at the same time?

Comment: I join the info from each lawyer page into a list called row. I add that row to a final list called results. I then convert that to a dataframe and write the dataframe to csv. The csv I shared. It takes a long time to run which is why a future improvement would be to look at parallelization/asyncio but that is more advanced topic.

Comment: So then I have to explicitly pass each profile link through s.get(), I was passing the variable link through as s.get(link). That is why it is running till now without stopping.

Comment: Let me know when it has run

Comment: I posted within an error I corrected in my code but forgot to correct in answer. Updated now.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I have tried by iterating over the links in final_list but it is running for long and I don't even know for how much long will it still run, and the .xls file which is to be created at the Desktop is also not being created. Is there a possibility that it has fallen into an infinite loop? If possible suggest what can be done.

Comment: I have posted a new question n this regard. If possible see to it and suggest. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544839/fetching-lawyer-details-from-different-links-of-a-website-using-bs4-in-python)

Comment: No. The code above is correct and generates the output I shared. It does take a while to run however. Did you look at the file?

Comment: Yes I have seen the .csv file you had shared, I have just changed it to .xls file so that it creates a excel file, and I have also iterated over the list lawyers. Actually the program is continuously running and I

Comment: It took maybe 15 minutes to complete for me.