# Fetching lawyer details from different links of a website using bs4 in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am an absolute beginner to Web Scraping using Python with very little knowledge in Python programming. I am just trying to extract the information of the lawyers in the Tennesse location. In the webpage ,there are multiple links, within which there are further more links about the categories of lawyers and within those are the lawyers details.

I have already extracted the links of the various city into a list and have also extracted the various categories of lawyers available in each of the city links. Furthermore I have extracted each of the lawyers url in separate categories and stored them in a separate set. Now I have iterated over those urls for fetching the details of the lawyers and finally writing them on to a .xls file. But while I am running my code the process is going on executing for and indefinite amount of time. I have to force stop the process and even no .xls file is being created at the desired location as stated in the program. What can be done? If possible suggest.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

final=[]
records=[]
with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get('https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/tennessee/', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

    cities = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#browse_view a')]
    for c in cities:
        r=s.get(c)
        s1=bs(r.content,'lxml')
        categories = [item['href'] for item in s1.select('.three_browse_columns:nth-of-type(2) a')]
        for c1 in categories:
            r1=s.get(c1)
            s2=bs(r1.content,'lxml')
            lawyers = [item['href'].split('*')[1] if '*' in item['href'] else item['href'] for item in
                       s2.select('.indigo_text .directory_profile')]



            for i in lawyers:
                r2 = s.get(i)
                s3 = bs(r2.content, 'lxml')
                name = s3.select_one('#lawyer_name').text
                category = s3.select_one('#attorney_profile_heading').text
                firm = s3.select_one('#firm_profile_page').text
                address = ' '.join([string for string in s3.select_one('#poap_postal_addr_block').stripped_strings][1:])
                practices = ' '.join([item.text for item in s3.select('#pa_list li')])
                records.append({'Names': name,'Category':category,'Address': address, 'Firm Name': firm,'Practice Area':practices})
df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Category','Address','Farm Name','Practice Areas'])
df=df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\lawyers.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

"I expected the program to complete its execution and create an .xls file, but it is going on executing and even I have no idea for how long will it require to complete it's execution. Is there any possibility that an infinite loop has occoured? If possible suggest."

Comment: Where and what am I doing wrong? Kindly suggest if possible.

Comment: I would start by adding a "print" statement at the start of each "for" loop so that you can get a feeling for what is happening.

Comment: I have checked them, placing print statement before each "for" loop thereby seeing the lists namely cities, categories and lawyers returning the url links as expected. But still the program is running continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the data that you're trying to scrape is too much and using BeautifulSoup will take a lot of time, I tried scraping [this website](https://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviations/) and even after dividing the search into four different program files it took about 12 hours to successfully complete the execution,I also tried your code for **only brentwood city** and it took about an hour. I see no infinite loop in your code! let it run and have patience.

Also your program has not created any .xml because it has not reached that part of code.

PS: I know this should be a comment but I currently don't have enough reputatuion to do so. Hope this answer helps you and also me to gain reputation to be able to comment next time.

Comment: Okay thanks for replying. As you said even after its long execution for about 12 hours does any .xls file gets created? Actually you have stated '.xml' that is why I am asking. If possible suggest what can be done?

Comment: Oh sorry it was a typo, I meant .xls file. BTW did you get any result yet or not?