# CSS related; targetting a special li class

Tags: html, css, slider

Need a bit of help with the following situation. 
I've a slider who's setup is like this (simplified):

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li class="current">...</li>
        <li class="center active">...</li>
        <li class="current">...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>


.slider li {opacity: 0.3;}
.slider li.center.active {opacity: 1;}
.slider li.current:first-child {opacity: 1;}  // this here doesn't work.
```

I can't use `.slider li:nth-child(2).current {opacity: 1;}`
because I'm using a slider, so the number if `li` tags is different.

Is there another way, other than changing the li classes, to change the opacity of  the first `current` class only.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of you code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ua60Ld31/5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below mentioned code:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li class="current">...</li>
        <li class="center active">...</li>
        <li class="current">...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
.slider li {opacity: 0.3;}
.slider li.center.active {opacity: 1;}
.slider li.current {opacity: 1;}
.slider li.center.active ~ li.current  {opacity: 0.3;}
```

Comment: I don't think this work if you add more element `.current` after `.center.active`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1jko09xq/1/

```
i think you need this try this
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation first current `<li>` is actually a second element of `<ul>` use this css

```
.slider li.current:nth-child(2) {opacity: 1;}
```

See working example :https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/a3w1bshr/

> In css we need to count position with overall elements and here its a second element of `<ul>`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that either. It's a slider, so the number if `li tags` can  change. In the example it's the second one, but because we're dealing with a slider here, it can also be the fifth `li tag`.

Comment: in that case add this css by jquery `$('.slider li.current').eq(0).css('opacity','1');`. Jquery rule is different from css and it will consider it as a first element of `.current`

Comment: Thank you for letting me about this. I wasn't aware this could be possible as well. Thanks to you, I definitely want to learn jquery this year. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional class to the li you want to change.

HTML:

```
  <div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li class="current sliderOpacity">...</li>
                <li class="center active">...</li>
                <li class="current">...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sliderOpacity {
opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't add an extra class.

Comment: Why couldn't you add an extra class?

Answer (score 0):

here you go sir

```css
.slider li,
.slider ul > .current ~ .current { opacity: 0.3; }

.slider li.center.active,
.slider ul > .current { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li class="current">...</li>
        <li class="center active">...</li>
        <li class="current">...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```