# nth-of-type sort of works for classes, but only with different nested tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I see many posts saying "*[Unfortunately, CSS doesn't provide a `:first-of-class` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447072/864233)*", but I'm seeing conflicting results.

A user provides an example that acts as a `:first-of-class` type selector in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2717515/864233).

The code they use is:

```css
.home .red:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <span>blah</span>
  <p class="red">first</p>
  <p class="red">second</p>
  <p class="red">third</p>
  <p class="red">fourth</p>
</div>
```

Which works as intended, with the `p` tag with **first** having a red border.

However, this is where things kind of break down.

When I use wrapping and inner elements of the same tag type, `:nth-of-type` no longer works.

```css
.home .red:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div>Does not work (when using <kbd>div</kbd> tags as both inner and outer)</div>
  <div class="red">first</div>
  <div class="red">second</div>
  <div class="red">third</div>
</div>
```

You can see this in the following [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/romellem/ksjLja0h/3/).

Does anyone know why `:nth-of-type` sort of works as a `:nth-of-class` selector when you have different tag types, but doesn't work when you use the same tag type?

Comment: If you look past the accepted answer to the second question, you'll see another answer by me which explains - quite thoroughly - why the accepted answer is flawed, and you would have had the answer to your question. In fact, Paulie_D's answer says pretty much the same thing I do, except they get straight to the point for the purposes of clarifying your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.red:nth-of-type(1)` means the first of it's type AND with the class of "red".

So

```
<div class="home">
  <div>Works (<code>p</code> tags)</div>
  <p class="red">first</p> /* works */
  <p class="red">second</p>
  <p class="red">third</p>
</div>
```

The first `p` ALSO has the class of "red" and so is selected.

and

```
<div class="home">
  <div>Does not work (<code>div</code> tags)</div> /* doesn't work */
  <div class="red">first</div>
  <div class="red">second</div>
  <div class="red">third</div>
</div>
```

The first `div` does **not** have a class of "red" and so is NOT selected.

Comment: "Because `.red:nth-of-type(1)` means the first of it's type **AND** with the class of `.red`" Thanks, I knew I was missing something. That helped give me that "ah ha" moment.

Answer (score 1):

if you change your `div` to `p` in your second example it will work, because the first `div` will have the red class

```css
.home .red:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div>Works (<kbd>p</kbd> tags)</div>
  <p class="red">first</p>
  <p class="red">second</p>
  <p class="red">third</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="home">
  <p>Does not work (<kbd>div</kbd> tags)</p>
  <div class="red">first</div>
  <div class="red">second</div>
  <div class="red">third</div>
</div>
```