# :first-of-type in table with multiple classes doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to catch **the first** `tr`with a specific class (`wpcw_fe_unit_pending`). But it doesn't work for some reason.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```css
tr.wpcw_fe_unit.wpcw_fe_unit_pending.wpcw_fe_module_group_1:first-of-type td.wpcw_fe_unit {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="wpcw_fe_course" class="wpcw_fe_table" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_module " id="wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Module 1</td>
      <td colspan="2">Topic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_unit wpcw_fe_unit_complete wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Unit 1</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit"><a href="">1st Unit - Done</a>
      </td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit_progress wpcw_fe_unit_progress_complete"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_unit wpcw_fe_unit_complete wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Unit 2</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit"><a href="">2nd Unit - Done</a>
      </td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit_progress wpcw_fe_unit_progress_complete"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_unit wpcw_fe_unit_pending wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Unit 3</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit"><a href="">3rd Unit - Done</a>
      </td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit_progress wpcw_fe_unit_progress_incomplete"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_unit wpcw_fe_unit_pending wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Unit 4</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit">4th Unit</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit_progress wpcw_fe_unit_progress_incomplete"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_unit wpcw_fe_unit_pending wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Unit 5</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit">5th Unit</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit_progress wpcw_fe_unit_progress_incomplete"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wpcw_fe_unit wpcw_fe_unit_pending wpcw_fe_module_group_1">
      <td>Unit 6</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit">6th Unit</td>
      <td class="wpcw_fe_unit_progress wpcw_fe_unit_progress_incomplete"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nerd/pen/pbyrOO/).

Comment: Because `:first-of-type` doesn't work that way. It selects the first element of its type under the parent and not the first element of its type which matches the class selectors.

Comment: A class is not a type, it's a class. You probably want a first-of-class pseudo-class but one doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh crap. Is there a possibility in css to solve this task?

Comment: There's actually no method currently in the CSS spec whereby you can select an element by the `nth` instance of a class.

Comment: Only CSS way would be to first set the property for all elements that have the required classes and then override it for all that are not the first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6447072/1063673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `first-of-type` pseudo class only looks at the ***element***. The ***class*** attribute is ignored.

> [**6.6.5.8. `:first-of-type`
>   pseudo-class**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#first-of-type-pseudo)
>
> Same as `:nth-of-type(1)`.
>
> The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the
>   first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent
>   element.