# css3 first-of-type not working

Tags: html, css, sass

Hi everybody I got a problem with first-of-type in sass i dont why it wont work if nth-of-type(2n) work . Any advice welcomed

/* this code i need but it wont work */

```
.menu-parts {

        float: left;

            &:first-of-type {
                ul>li:first-of-type {
                    background-color: red;
                }
            }
      }
```

/* this code work but i wont this */

```
.menu-parts {

        float: left;

            &:nth-of-type(2n) {
                ul>li:first-of-type {
                    background-color: red;
                }
            }
      }



  <div class="menu-parts">

              <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array( 

                  'theme_location' => 'part_one',
                  'container' => false,
                  'menu_class' => 'nav_one'

                ));
                ?>

            </div>

            <div class="menu-parts">
              <ul>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> references</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i> about me</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i> abilities</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: `first-of-type` works on tags, not classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)