# CSS first-of-type stopped working after adding new section class

Tags: css, css-selectors, first-of-type

Following on from a previous answer, i am using first-of-type to target the first menuSection like this...

```css
.menuSection:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

This is working correctly, but when I throw in some extra sections with different classes it stops working...

```css
.menuSection:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <section class="new_menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="new_menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `first-of-type` selector unfortunately doesn't refer to the first appearance of a *class*, but of the *tag* type, in your case `section`. So in combination with the class selector this doesn't select anything in your example.

If you know how many sections there will be, you can use `section:nth-of-type(x)` without a class (see example below), but otherwise the only solution is to assign a seperate class to that one section and use that in the selector.

```css
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <section class="new_menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="new_menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Heavily [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name) but because it's not intuitive I'll post an answer. The important thing to realize is the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector is for **type** meaning it looks at the element (i.e. `div`, `p`, etc) and goes off of that. The other important thing to note is it looks at **siblings**

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

You are trying to use to do this for classes so behind the scenes what it's doing is saying "Okay so you want all items of `.menuSection` so let me look at the type -- okay that's a `div`so let me try to grab the first one of the divs and if it has a class of `menuSection` I'm going to apply this style.

To illustrate this more clearly -- in your example you have `new_menuSection` as a separate style and you were wondering why is the style not applying to the first `.menuSection`. Like I said, it looks at the type so if you change the type of your `.new_menuSection` to another element, it works as expected.

```css
.menuSection:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="new_menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```