# Applying first and last child to a certain <tr> id via css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Basically I want to be able to remove `margins` below and above the **'non'** first and last child duplicates. So I have tried to target the `row` that has duplicate `id's`.. in this case `#Day2` and `#Day6`, then I've tried to select the `:first-child` and the `:last-child`

```
tr#Day2:first-child td, tr#Day6:first-child td { margin-top: 0px !important; }
tr#Day2:last-child td, tr#Day6:last-child td { margin-bottom: 0px !important; }
```

I'm not sure if a `css` only way is able to achieve what I want or if I'm on a somewhat right path with what I'm currently doing.

My attempt to use `jquery` to do this is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            var seen = {};
            $('table tr td').each(function() {
                var txt = $(this).text();
                if (seen[txt])
                    $(this).css("margin-bottom", "0px");
                else
                   seen[txt] = true;
            });
        });
   });
</script>
```

Though this doesn't seem to even remove the margin of a duplicate, nor does my css attempt I'm sure there is a way. Perhaps I cannot use `:first-child` and `:last-child` with a `tr` `id`? If so is there any other way to achieve what I want?

I greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

**JSFiddle**
Please view my [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjv97fz/5/).

**

### Solution

**
All achieved without the need for jQuery. Please find the working edition here.
Thanks @Marcin for pointing me towards the solution.

[JSFiddle: View Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjv97fz/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only workaround for this:

```
.Day2 { margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; }
.Day2 ~ .Day2 td { margin-top: 5px; }
```

This sets only bottom margin on each `.Day2` and then, if there is any `.Day2` before, sets `margin-top` to 5px;

Taken from [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

*You shouldn't use the same `id` on more than one element. Use `class` instead (for example `class="day1"`).*

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Marcin however I have to use the same CSS for all days, as you see here if I add to `.Day5` and `.Day3` it messes it up: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjv97fz/6/) In this case the `.Day2 ~ .Day2` isn't working?

Comment: I think `.Day2 ~ .Day2 td` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin you got me on the right track. I just had to add `.Day2 td { margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px }` to the first one also.