# CSS Select First Row With Class

Tags: css

I have rows like this:

```
<tr class="team_2">Team Member</tr>
<tr class="team_2">Team Member</tr>
<tr class="team_1">Team Member</tr>
<tr class="team_2">Team Member</tr>
<tr class="team_1">Team Member</tr>
```

I want to highlight the **first member of each team** as team captain. I tried this:

```
table tbody tr.team_2:first-of-type, table tbody tr.team_1:first-of-type {
background: red;
}
```

This highlighted the first row, but not the third row (captain for team 1). Is this type of selector possible?

Comment: Have consider use "class" attribute? only set a class, for example "captain" to the captain tags instead of using selectors that you can't do that you want with selectors

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kjwovpyr/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to do it backwards, see [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447072/1763258). Basically set ALL of those classes to the **highlight** color, then you look further down the DOM and reset any subsequent, sibling classes to the **default**.

Also, you should put `td` elements in your table:

```css
.team_2, .team_1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.team_1 ~ .team_1 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.team_2 ~ .team_2 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="team_2"><td>Team Member</td></tr>
<tr class="team_2"><td>Team Member</td></tr>
<tr class="team_1"><td>Team Member</td></tr>
<tr class="team_2"><td>Team Member</td></tr>
<tr class="team_1"><td>Team Member</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are `<td>` elements in the table, I just removed them for simplification. The real rows are a lot bigger. Thanks for the cool trick!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would just add a class to the team member and target that specific class.

**HTML**

```
<tr class="team_2">
 <td class="captain">Team Member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="team_1">
 <td>Team Member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="team_1">
 <td class="captain">Team Member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="team_2">
 <td>Team Member</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.captain{.....}
```

---

EDIT: I have edited my answer as the one Ben gave is better aligned to your question.