# CSS Selector for first nested element with class

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

Trying to select the first instance of an element of class 'vidplayicon' in each 'imgClass' div.

here is my HTML

```
<div class="imgClass">
  <div>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="vidplayicon">test</p> <!-- this should be selected-->
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="vidplayicon">test</p>
  </div>
</div>
...
<div class="imgClass">
  <div>
    <p class="vidplayicon">test</p> <!-- this should be selected-->
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="vidplayicon">test</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="vidplayicon">test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
.imgClass  div .vidplayicon:first-of-type{
    color:red;
}
```

but it's not working can I have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first-of-type it's suposed to be used with tag names, not classes.

Take a look at [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)