# Need first-of-type to work on first paragraph, but not on nested first paragraphs

Tags: css-selectors

I have successfully put a large first letter on the first paragraph on blog posts. But if there are other first paragraphs in the post (examples: the first paragraph of a blockquote, the first paragraph in an embedded podcast player) they are also displaying the large first letter.

I have tried some examples from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name) but I'm not sure if this article is covering my situation or not. I'm new to the idea of adjacent sibling selectors. I'll share the code I tried to implement by (assumedly) telling any other p:first-of-type::first-letter incidents after my first incident to not have the styling...

```
.single .post .entry-content p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  float: left;
  width: 0.75em;
  font-size: 600%;
  font-family: alice, serif;
  line-height: 78%;
}

.single .post .entry-content p:first-of-type::first-letter ~ p {
  float: none;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: lora, serif;
  line-height: 0%;
}
```

The large letters remain in block quotes and the embedded podcast player. How would I explain that first letters of first paragraphs inside of divs which are nested inside the .entry-content area should not have the first letter styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your targeted paragraph is a direct child of `.entry-content` then you can use the *direct children* selector `>` :

```
.single .post .entry-content > p:first-of-type::first-letter {}
```

By using the direct children selector you don't select descendant elements that are nested deeper than direct children. And by adding `:first-of-type` or `nth-of-type(n)`, you select only your paragraph within those childrens.

Comment: Here is a post where that's happening. The first paragraph of the post is fine, it's the embedded podcast player that is showing two large first letter situations. What I want is only the first letter of the post to be large, not the ones in the podcast player.  https://sallieborrink.com/aqsl-004-you-are-not-enough-and-thats-the-whole-point/

Comment: I tested the solution i gave you by adding this rule in the inspector : **.single .post .entry-content > p:first-of-type::first-letter {color: red;}** and only the first lettre of the first paragraph was red

Comment: Thank you Pierre-Yves. Your solution does work! I had not understood the concept of "direct children selectors". That's the isolation that I needed. Thank you!

Comment: With pleasure !. Consider *accepting* my answer if it was what you were looking for ;)