# first of type with global class is not the same as if it is the local class

Tags: html, css, angular

When we have this part of code:

```
<div *ngFor="element of elements1" class="element"></div>
<div *ngFor="element of elements2" class="element"></div>
```

And class Element:

```
.element {
color:red;
}
.element:first-of-type {
color:blue;
}
```

And we have two cases:

- The first one is when the class `element` is global. 
  *In this case just the first element of `elements1` will be blue*
- The second one is when the class "element" is local.
  *In this case fist elements of both of the arrays will be blue*

**Why behavior in both cases isn't the same?**

Answer (score 0):

first-of-type will get the element type using the class, so for example if the class is assigned on a `p` then the `p` should be the first of it's type to work so if there is any other `p` even from another class it will not detect it.

```css
p:first-of-type {color:blue}
.myclass1:first-of-type {color:red}
.myclass2:first-of-type {color:green}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>This text should appear as normal</div>
  <p>This text should be blue.</p>
  <p class="myclass1">This text should appear red.</p>
  <p class="myclass2">This text should appear green.</p>
</div>
```

check this also:
[CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

Comment: Yes, you can use first-of-type with classes: https://codepen.io/adripanico/pen/oNgEMOO

Comment: then why the snippet in my answer is not working?

Comment: It's working, the problem is that the type in this case is a paragraph and once it matches the first paragraph, the other rules are not applicable. See this other snippet in which I'm mixing paragraphs and spans: https://codepen.io/adripanico/pen/ZEYrMJq

Comment: Thanks that was good to know i'll change my answer

Comment: but still it uses the class only to get the type and then to select the first of that type.

Comment: Exactly. The pseudo-selector applies only to element level. But you can define it using classes and the resulting CSS is correct.

Comment: so can you remove the downvote :)

Comment: This kind of discussions helps a lot and I'm not defensive I accept other opinion if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div 
  *ngFor="element of elements1; let first = first;" 
  class="element" 
  [ngStyle]="first && {'color': 'blue'}">
</div>
```

This will set the color only for the first div.

Comment: I don't need another implementation. I want to understand the behavior.

Comment: @Student Okay, Quentin's answer explains the reason. If you have further issues replicate your issue in a stackBlitz or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

`:first-of-type` means "first of **type**" and not "first that matches the previous bit of the selector".

The class is irrelevent. The element type is **div**.

```css
.element {
  color: red;
}

.element:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="element">This is the first div in the section</div>
  <div class="element">
      This is the second div in the section
      <div class="element">This is the first div in the div</div>
      <div class="element">This is the second div in the div</div>
  </div>
  <p class="element">This is the first p in the section</p>
  <p class="element">This is the second p in the section</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but why second case working with another behavior?

Comment: @Student — The differences between your two cases are unclear. You should provide a [mcve] that shows the HTML (and not the Angular template).