# CSS :first-child to work with classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say i have this markup:

```
<div class='current'>
</div>
<div class='current'>
</div>
<div class='current'>
</div>
<div class='current'>
</div>
<div class='current'>
</div>
```

Now these divs are not necessarily next to each other in the markup, but could be spread throughout the page.

Can i target only the first occurrence of class "current" using CSS only, i'd ideally like to avoid using javascript (for now)?

Ie.

```
.current:first-child {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: When you say they're spread all over the page, does it mean they occur just about *anywhere* in the page or do they all at least have a common parent?

Comment: Yes, they have a common parent of div class="group"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
.current:nth-child(1){
    background:red;
}
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Uhhh, how is `:nth-child(1)` different from `:first-child`, besides the fact that the former doesn't work on IE7 and IE8 while the latter does?

Comment: I have added the test with :first-child - http://www.webdevout.net/test?019 Works great.

Answer (score 6):

`:first-child` targets elements that are first children, not first occurrence of a given class. So this will target all elements with `current` class, that are first children. It can be all of them if they are in different places on a page or none at all.

It sounds like you may be looking for css3 selector `first-of-type`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615559/106224) two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447072/106224) (along with [this new one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224)), CSS3 doesn't bake in a pseudo-class that selects the first element of its class (unlike `:first-of-type` which selects by type).

You can always use `:first-child` if `.current` is guaranteed to be the first child of `.group`:

```
.group .current:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

But if it's not guaranteed to be, then based on your comments and the answer link, since they all share the same parent you can do this instead:

```
.group .current {
    background: red;
}

.group .current ~ .current {
    background: transparent; /* Or whatever your default is */
}
```

The general sibling combinator `~` ignores other elements that may not be `.current`. All these rules work in IE7+.

Comment: as metioned in the comment above, I have added the test page with :first-child at http://www.webdevout.net/test?019 and it shows that you can select the first .current even without all of the .current being placed within the same parent or any particular order. Am I missing something?

Comment: @spliter: The one that's highlighted is the first child of `html body ul li` so it gets matched. If you move the `ul` elsewhere, that `div` would still be matched.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @BoltClock. Tried that and indeed, the test was not very accurate in this case. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If they are spread throughout the page, you can not get what you need with pure CSS solution. Even with `first-of-type` unless the elements are on the same DOM level. Check [the example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0M) to see that you can not select the elements.

On the other hand once I move the third .current to the same DOM level where I already have the second one, [I get only the second item selected](http://www.webdevout.net/test?016), as it's the first .current on this level.

On the other hand it's a very [short one-liner in JS](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/Sq2Hb/)

Don't overcomplicate things ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it's spread throughout the page, you can't target it with css.