# first-child not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

Should this work am I going crazy?

```css
.project.work:first-child:before {
  content: 'Projects';
}
.project.research:first-child:before {
  content: 'Research';
}
```

```html
<div class="project work">
  <p>abcdef</p>
</div>
<div class="project work">
  <p>abcdef</p>
</div>
<div class="project work">
  <p>abcdef</p>
</div>
<div class="project research">
  <p>abcdef</p>
</div>
```

`projects:first-child` works fine, `research:first-child` doesn't stick. Any ideas?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvwYD/) It doesn't work, but whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `:first-child` only selects the first child. Nothing else.

Comment: .project.research:first-child Isn't that the first of its kind though?

Comment: It is, but it's not the first child of its parent.

Comment: So it's looking at the parent not at the child? Should I use Jquery then to select it?

Comment: why use first-child? couldn't you just use .project.work p:before and .project.research p:before

Comment: @uriah: No, it's looking at the child, but here your first `.project.research` is actually the third child of whatever contains your `div`s, even if it's `body`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:first-child` only selects the first child of its parent. Nothing else.

As mentioned in a few of my other answers on the site ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615559/106224) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447072/106224) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649908/106224) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224)), there is no `:first-of-class` pseudo-class. If you are looking to apply styles to the first of each class of your `div` elements, a solution is to apply the styles to all children of that class, and a general sibling selector to undo the styles from subsequent siblings.

Your CSS would then look like this:

```
.project.work:before {
    content: 'Work';
}

.project.research:before {
    content: 'Research';
}

.project.work ~ .project.work:before, 
.project.research ~ .project.research:before {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: There isn't a way in pure CSS to apply this dynamically (i.e. without having to hardcode the extra classes if you decide to add more later on), though. Once you add more classes, you have to add them to your CSS manually in this pattern.

Comment: Perfect, apply to all and undo siblings. Thanks @boltclock So if I if have add another class like `.project.photography` it wont work?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VvwYD/3/) It repeats the **Photo** :first-child have I done something wrong?

Comment: @uriah: Your last selector should be `.project.work ~ .project.work:before, .project.photo ~ .project.photo:before,
.project.research ~ .project.research:before`, you had an extra `.project.work ~` in the Photo part. The `~` selector doesn't limit itself to adjacent siblings, unlike `+`, so you don't need the extra work selector.

Comment: Sorry, should [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VvwYD/4/) work? Shouldn't Photo only appear once?

Comment: @uriah: Oops, you also have to remove the first `:before`. This is why I hate having to write long selectors :) [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VvwYD/5/)

Comment: my mistake too, I should have seen that. Thanks! Saved me a headache, do you know what levels of IE support this method?

Comment: @uriah: It's a lot harder to get it wrong if you split the selector into multiple lines: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/VvwYD/7/. This will work in IE8 and greater. It won't work in IE7 due to the use of `:before`.

Comment: IE8 is fine, many thanks to @boltclock for explaining everything to clearly.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: This is, like, the fourth time I've used this technique to answer a question. I feel like I need a canonical answer to point future questions to...

Comment: :-) (I've felt the same way about some JavaScript topics.) This add-to-all-then-remove-from-siblings trick is *definitely* going in my toolkit.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Found an old question that could use a bit of help, so I chipped in :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224

Answer (score 1):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-child-pseudo):

> Same as `:nth-child(1)`. The `:first-child` pseudo-class represents an element that is the first child of some other element.

`.project.research` is not the first child of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this CSS:

```
.project.work p:first-child:before {content:'Projects';}
.project.research p:first-child:before {content:'Research';}
```

or

```
.project.work > p:first-child:before {content:'Projects';}
.project.research > p:first-child:before {content:'Research';}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VvwYD/2/)

That matches the first child *of* an element with the classes "project" and "work" (or "project" and "research"). You don't have to use `p:first-child` if it may not be a `p` element, you could use `*:first-child` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I would only like to select the first of its kind and apply the CSS not every element. This select all of them.

Comment: @uriah: Ah. I don't think you can do that without changing your markup. I don't think even CSS3 selectors have a way of selecting the first element in a container with a given pair of class names. Even `:first-of-type` would apply to the element type, irrespective of class.