# CSS argument for "if first child is"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need a CSS selector for inside a div but I want it to only select the element if its the first element of a specific class inside that div.

Comment: "for inside a div"? "the first element of a specific class inside that div"?

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615518/css-selector-to-select-first-element-of-a-given-class

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As your title implies "if first child is": `div > .test:first-child` will select the first child of any `<div>` *if* it has the class `test`.

But if the first child of the `<div>` *doesn't* have the class `test`, then it won't continue searching the `<div>` until it finds a child with the class `test` — it just won't match anything. I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: +1 For the right answer. And OP (now?) _is_ clear about being the element of a specific class.