# CSS select the first child from elements with particular attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

Lets say that we have the following code:

```xml
<node>
  <element bla="1"/>
  <element bla="2"/>
  <element bla="3"/>
  <element bla="3"/>
  <element bla="3"/>
  <element bla="4"/>
</node>
```

How would you go about selecting the first child that has attribute equal to 3? I was thinking that perhaps this could do the job:

```
element[bla="3"]:first-child
```

...but it did not work

Comment: Are you using CSS to style XML markup or something?

Comment: no, just to illustrate the problem

Comment: Next time provide an HTML sample if you're styling HTML, in case it affects what kind of answers you get. My answer covers a few cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `:first-child` pseudo-class only looks at the first child node, so if the first child isn't an `element[bla="3"]`, then nothing is selected.

There isn't a similar filter pseudo-class for attributes. An easy way around this is to select every one then exclude what comes after the first (this trick is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615559/106224)):

```
element[bla="3"] {
}

element[bla="3"] ~ element[bla="3"] {
    /* Reverse the above rule */
}
```

This, of course, only works for applying styles; if you want to pick out that element for purposes other than styling (since your markup appears to be arbitrary XML rather than HTML), you'll have to use something else like `document.querySelector()`:

```
var firstChildWithAttr = document.querySelector('element[bla="3"]');
```

Or an XPath expression:

```
//element[@bla='3'][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
:not([bla="3"]) + [bla="3"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p bla="1">EL1</p>
  <p bla="2">EL2</p>
  <p bla="3">EL3</p>
  <p bla="3">EL3</p>
  <p bla="3">EL3</p>
  <p bla="4">EL4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve user's problem. Also, adding your answer in form of a snippet would improve you answer and prove that it works.

Comment: Picard, thank you. I've just added the snippet. You could make sure that the solution does select the 1st item with bla = 3.