# Select every other element of class using css3

Tags: css

Given an `ul` with a structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="product">...</li>
    <li class="product">...</li>
    <li class="product">...</li>
    <li class="product">...</li>
    <li class="spot">...</li>
    <li class="product">...</li>
    <li class="product">...</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way using CSS3 to target every other occurance of a `li` with the class product.

I've tried using both nth-of-child and nth-of-type in various configurations to no luck, both seem to target every other li element regardless of the class is has.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Comment: I've tried using .product:nth-of-type(2n) and .product:nth-child(2n) but both will count the li element with class=spot in the flow and hit the li element right after the one with class=spot.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10012244/206403

Comment: @Jonathan no I don't think the issue is the same

Comment: @HansSkov How does it differ? Elements are either odd or even. You want to know how to select all of the evens, or all of the odds. That was the question asked elsewhere, and an answer was provided.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: He wants all even (or odd) `.product`s, not just all even (or odd) `<li>`s.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I want to select every other element with a specific class

Comment: @Rocket So the only difference is the presence of a class in the selector? I personally don't think that merits a new question.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: given the difficulty we're having providing an answer, it seems to...

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I think it does since `.product:nth-child(odd)` doesn't work as expected.  This selects elements that are class product AND also an odd child, it doesn't select the odd numbered `.product` elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I style even and odd elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with plain CSS (in any way that I yet know of), however a plain-JavaScript solution is pretty simple:

```
var​ lis = document.querySelectorAll('li.product');

for (var i=0,len=lis.length;i<len;i++){
    if (i%2 == 0){
        lis[i].className = 'oddProduct';
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ktkt3/1/).

jQuery could be used instead (as could, presumably, any *other* JavaScript library), but it's certainly not *required*.

Comment: No, what he's looking for is to only consider those with the class.  So in his example html, it would be elements 1,3 and 6  (.spot is skipped).  nth-child will match 1,3,7.  What he wants is what `:even` in jquery does.  Don't think you can do it in pure css.

Comment: @HansSkov, sorry I couldn't come up with a pure-css solution, but the JavaScript version I posted does work. I just hope that it's of some use to you... =/

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the effort, seems like JavaScript is the only way to go. I'll give you credit since you're the first answer

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you can't with plain CSS3. The nth-child selectors work on element selectors, not classes. So, `li:nth-child(even)` works, but `.product:nth-child(even)` does not.

[You will need jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) to achieve this.

Comment: This could absolutely be achieved with jQuery, but it's not 'required' as such.

Comment: Good point - jQuery isn't required - but JavaScript would be.

Answer (score 4):

Could your problem be solved by overriding spot and selecting every other li (like others have mentioned)? Also, you could select the ul by class name.

How is this:

```
.ul_class li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #CCC;
}

.spot {
    background: green;
}
```

The only glitch that might end up looking odd is when 2 spot li`s are right next to each other. I think in every other case spot should look fine.

I also found that this worked fine in chrome:

```
li.product:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```