# How to select the first child node with class via CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)
>   [CSS selector to select first element of a given class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615518/css-selector-to-select-first-element-of-a-given-class)

I have an HTML structure here.

```
<div id = "container">
    <p class = "txt">abc</p>
    <p class = "vs">123</p>
    <p class = "txt">abc</p>
    <p class = "txt">abc</p>
    <p class = "vs">456</p>
</div>
```

How could I select the first p whose class is "vs" to set the font color to "red" via CSS selector?
I mean the expectation is that only 123 is red, but 456 and abc are black.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) and [CSS selector to select first element of a given class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615518/css-selector-to-select-first-element-of-a-given-class)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to the first duplicate doesn't get it right. You can't use `:nth-of-type(1)` or `:first-of-type` here as they are all p elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/TWYTy/ particular to this scenario u can use css like this

    #container p.vs:nth-child(2n)
    {
        color:red;
    }​