# YUI first child of Node matching a given selector

Tags: css-selectors, yui

I have seen the [questions of similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188508/how-to-select-the-first-child-node-with-class-via-css-selector), but they are not exactly the same.

First, I am using YUI (3.2.0 for compatibility with Liferay 6.0).

I already have a `Node` reference.  My goal would be to get the first child of that `Node` which matches a given CSS selector.  At first, I was doing this:

```
...
parse: function(node) {
    var title = node.one('>span, >div, >a, >h1');
    ...
},
...
```

And this works in Firefox, Chrome and IE 9+.  However, we must support IE 8.  So I dig in and find the w3c reference stating:

> [A child selector is made up of **two or more** selectors separated by ">"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

This seems to indicate that, per the spec, a parent is required, even though in practice that doesn't seem to be the case.  So I search a little more and see that jQuery actually mentions that this specific case is being deprecated:

> [Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future
>   release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative
>   selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

I cannot find explicit mention of this case in the YUI documentation, but I still don't think it would be safe to use it (and it's not supported in IE8 anyway).  I tried a bunch of things including using `*>span, *>div, ...`, `*:first-child+span, ...`, but they did not work.  So what I am left with is this:

```
var title = node.get('children').filter('>span, >div, >a, >h1').item(0);
```

But this seems inelegant and inefficient as the code behind it would have a lot of loops (since filter will not short circuit and all I want is the first match).  Anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: [Selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) has a clearer description of the grammar; the child selector, which is a combinator, requires having a selector on each side in order to say "this is a child of that", hence the "two or more" bit. Selector libraries employ a syntax that is currently non-standard. However, [Selectors API 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#relative-selector-string) is looking to allow a combinator at the start of a selector string, calling it a relative selector string.

Comment: @BoltClock, great references.  Any idea which browsers support which selector levels?  A quick google doesn't seem to turn much up...

Comment: @BoltClock, it turns out IE8 does work, and your links to Selectors API forced me to reconfirm.  [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJTAZ/6/).  If you would like to write something up, i would be happy to give you the answer.

Comment: The latest versions of all browsers currently support Selectors 3 and Selectors API 1. Some may support bits and pieces of Selectors 4 and API 2 as hidden gems... as you've found.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, maybe it makes sense to take a step back. Currently your requirement is framed as, "match this CSS selector." Can you frame it instead as, "get first child of this node that is a span, a div, an anchor, or an h1" (or something similar?)

If so, ditch the selector engine. Instead, call node.get('children') and then iterate through the resulting NodeList -- your iterator function can simply check to see if the node name is of the right value and short-circuit if so. That should give you solid performance, and should be fairly readable as well.

Comment: Good suggestion, that would work in my case as I am just matching tag names.  With a good helper method it should behave just fine.  On a side note, I just read your book...  Submitted one errata (erratum?) as well :)

Comment: You could use the NodeList.first() function to search.  This function is provided by http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/nodelist-extras

Comment: @John, that link says YUI version 3.3, and I am forced to use 3.2.0 as it is provided by Liferay 6.0 which is our current production deployment.

Comment: nodelist-extras should work with YUI 3.2, too.  YUI 3.3 is simply the latest version with which the module was tested.