# With CSS only: Select first occurrence of class throughout whole document

Tags: css, css-selectors

We have a DOM like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> <!--// No "copyright" in this node //-->
        <div class="content">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="copyright">...</div> <!--// DISPLAY THIS ONE //-->
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="copyright">...</div> <!--// Hide this one //-->
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="copyright">...</div> <!--// Hide this one too, etc. //-->
    </div>
    <!--// etc. //-->
</div>
```

All elements with class "copyright" must be hidden, with exception of the very first one.

We tried to apply this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615518/css-selector-to-select-first-element-of-a-given-class), but unfortunately with no success. It must be a CSS only solution. Any idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

In this case, each `.copyright` is the first and only one of its kind in `.inner`, so you need to select by `.inner` instead. If you don't need to apply any special rules to the first child, you don't need to use the approach I describe in that other question; simply use this to hide the other elements:

```
.inner ~ .inner .copyright {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Btw. I need that to use the first occurrence as footer when printing the site (in Firefox): @media print { .copyright { position: fixed; bottom: 0; } .inner ~ .inner .copyright { display: none; } }

Comment: Sorry to disturb again, but we have forgotten an important detail: What if the first "inner"-node does not contain a "copyright" class?

Comment: That means you have to check for an `.inner` that contains a `.copyright`, which you can't do using pure CSS. You'll need JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This is still the top answer on Google for "css select first occurrence of class" so adding the simple technique I found to work.

This solution doesn't specifically solve the OP but does allow you to select the first element with a class amongst siblings.

You can use a combination of the sibling and not selectors as shown in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tscxnag/)

For example:

```
.my-class:not(.my-class ~ .my-class) {
  background: red;
}
```

How does this work?

The sibling selector (`~`) selects elements which are somewhere after other elements.

So this would select every element **except** the first one:

```
.my-class ~ .my-class {
  background: red;
}
```

We then just use the `:not` selector to reverse this, i.e. select only the first element.

I have only tested this on Chrome but think it should work on most modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egsSf/)

```
div.inner > .copyright { display:none; }
div.inner:first-child .copyright { display:block; background:#000; }
```

​

Comment: We have forgotten an important detail: What if the first "inner"-node does not contain a "copyright" class?