# Selecting the first-child with a given class, how?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html and I want to show only the first ".xpto" element.
My problem is that I'm removing the class .xpto dynamically, so when I do it, the first .xpto element will be the second inner div. How can I accomplish this?

```
<div>
    <div class="xpto"></div>
    <div class="xpto"></div>
    <div class="xpto"></div>
    <div class="xpto"></div>
</div>
```

I tried, :first-child, :first-of-type and :nth-child(1n) but nothing worked.
Any ideas? (CSS only)

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/7YRAF/

Comment: Isn't there an `:nth-of-type()` pseudo selector?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain a bit more.  Your example confused me further.

Comment: Oooh, nevermind. `:nth-of-type()` and `:first-of-type()` only apply to element tags, not classes or IDs.

Comment: .. and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615518/css-selector-to-select-first-element-of-a-given-class .. see BoltClock's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this is not entirely possible with CSS, this would work with the current example:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxrxe/)

```
div:not(.xpto) + div.xpto {
    display:block;
}
```

It basically just selects the succeeding `.xpto` element if its previous element doesn't have the class `.xpto`. Since you're removing the class, the 'first' element is selected. This obviously wouldn't work in **all** instances though, therefore you should just use jQuery for this since you're already using it.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4vTf/)

```
$('div > div.xpto:first').addClass('visible');
```

For an alternative, you could also do something like this:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9Tr7/)

```
div > .xpto {
    display:block;
}
div > .xpto ~ .xpto {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Great and clean solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give that wrapping div a class name, then you can use the first-child pseudo selector.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper div:first-child {
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: No you can't Matt, once you remove the .xpto class from the first div, it's not :first-child anymore. Please try it.

Comment: Hi, the .xpto classes have no bearing on using :first-child. You are targeting the first div in the .wrapper parent. The class on the inner divs can be anything, it doesn't come into play. I updated the code to show this. Remember, you need to insert some content into the div, otherwise when you flip to display:block; nothing is going to show. I've created a fiddle that shows this at: http://jsfiddle.net/9KbB5/

Comment: Matt your fiddle doesn't mirror my situation. If you try that approach, using my fiddle you'll see why :first-child won't do it.
Also, check Josh's answer, which lead me to the solution. Thanks!