# How to select the first type of child of a particular CSS using CSS selector

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum 2 </p>
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section1">section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
  <div class="section1">section 4</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</form>`
```

CSS:

```
#myForm div.section1:first {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Question: How to write CSS selector to select the first section1 CSS class under the form with text 'section 2'

The above CSS is not working

Comment: @NenadVracar `first-of-type` is not working for this example though: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u40cbop2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target it like that, but you can do something like this bellow. Basically overwriting the rest with the default.

A much better approach would be to have different markup.

```css
#myForm div.section1 {
  font-size:1.5em;color:red;
}

#myForm div.section1 ~ .section1 {
  font-size:1em;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum 2 </p>
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section1">section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
  <div class="section1">section 4</div>    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you can't target it this way though? I thought `#myForm div.section1:first-of-type` should work?

Comment: @CallanHeard: My answer below explains it - section1 isn't an element, but a class, and :first-of-type only sorts through elements.

Comment: You might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name

Answer (score 0):

There is no `:first` selector.

As discussed in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615559/6252717), there is no `:first-of-class` selector either, just a `:first-of-type` one. The linked answer also supposes a workaround, which for your answer looks like this:

```css
#myForm {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#myForm > div.section1 {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: red;
}
#myForm > div.section1 ~ div.section1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section1">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
  <div class="section1">Section 4</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</form>
```

This works by setting all `.section1` divs to a certain style, then re-setting them to their original style with another definition using the `~` selector.

Comment: Ah this explains it much better! Not sure why someone downvoted..

Comment: @CallanHeard: I posted a different answer before because I misread the question, then edited it; see the edit log for details if interested.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would make `#myForm div.section1:nth-of-type(2) { font-size: 1.5em; color: red; }`

Comment: That would only work for the markup at hand, but it doesn't solve the problem of styling the first element of class section1. Also, since this is your second answer, note that you can delete answers you don't think are fitting anymore to remove them from the question.